# What's the use of do while(0) when we define a macro?

Tags: c, macros, linux-kernel

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Do-While and if-else statements in C/C++ macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros)
>   [do { … } while (0) — what is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

I'm reading the linux kernel and I found many macros like this:

```
#define INIT_LIST_HEAD(ptr) do { \
    (ptr)->next = (ptr); (ptr)->prev = (ptr); \
} while (0)
```

Why do they use this rather than define it simply in a {}?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can follow it with a semicolon and make it look and act more like a function.
It also works with if/else clauses properly then.

Without the while(0), your code above would not work with

```
if (doit) 
   INIT_LIST_HEAD(x);
 else 
   displayError(x);
```

since the semicolon after the macro would "eat" the else clause, and the above wouldn't even compile.

Comment: But the OP's question stands. Why not just { (ptr)->next ... } instead of do { (ptr)->next ... } while (0);?

Comment: arno explained that. It would expand to  "{ (ptr)->next ... };" thus, a statement followed by a second statement. If syntax however is "if ( expression ) statement else statement" . The else would not be associated with any if, since you would have written "if ( expression ) statement statement" (one "{ ... }" and one ";" statement).

Comment: As Amo said, it's a clever trick that allows a macro to *be* a C statement that must end with a semicolon.  It makes the macro act exactly like a function call, so far as statement construction and termination (with ';') is concerned.

Comment: Note, however, that in this case it's all completely unnecessary, as the body of the macro could be written much more cleanly as: `(ptr)->next=(ptr)->prev=(ptr)`.

Comment: @JoshK the loop will be executed only once because while(0) is a false condition. However, an optimizing compiler will get ride of the `do {stat}while(0)` & replace with only `stat` because anyway, it's happening only once.

Answer (score 47):

It allows you to group several statements into one macro.

Assume you did something like:

```
if (foo) 
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(bar);
```

If the macro was defined without the encapsulating do { ... } while (0);, the above code would expand to

```
if (foo)
    (bar)->next = (bar);
    (bar)->prev = (bar);
```

This is clearly not what was intended, as only the first statement will be executed if foo holds. The second statement would be executed regardless of whether foo holds.

Edit: Further explanation at http://c-faq.com/cpp/multistmt.html and http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/cpp/Swallowing-the-Semicolon.html#Swallowing-the-Semicolon

Comment: This doesn't explain the do .. while(0) part of the macro, just the use of {} braces.

Comment: do {} while (0) part is explained in the post this one is dup of.

Comment: SPWorley, adobriyan: Actually, it looks like this post's author added links explaining the do {} while (0).