# C multi-line macro: do/while(0) vs scope block

Tags: c, macros, multiline

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What’s the use of do while(0) when we define a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro)
>   [Why are there sometimes meaningless do/while and if/else statements in C/C++ macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macr) 
>   [do { … } while (0)  what is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

I've seen some multi-line C macros that are wrapped inside a do/while(0) loop like:

```
#define FOO \
  do { \
    do_stuff_here \
    do_more_stuff \
  } while (0)
```

What are the benefits (if any) of writing the code that way as opposed to using a basic block:

```
#define FOO \
  { \
    do_stuff_here \
    do_more_stuff \
  }
```

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/

Comment: Actually there is another way to get things right. ({...}) can do the same thing as do {} while(0). Ref: http://www.bruceblinn.com/linuxinfo/DoWhile.html

Comment: @wuxb: the `({...})` construct is a GCC extension and is not supported by ISO standard C.

Comment: This is also a recommended approach by CERT: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/PRE10-C.+Wrap+multistatement+macros+in+a+do-while+loop

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Andrey Tarasevich provides the following explanation:

1. [On Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.c/c/xGZxls194mI/m/dEIpTKz2okMJ)
2. [On bytes.com](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/219859-do-while-0-macro-substitutions#post885394)

[Minor changes to formatting made. Parenthetical annotations added in square brackets `[]`].

> The whole idea of using 'do/while' version is to make a macro which will
> expand into a regular statement, not into a compound statement. This is
> done in order to make the use of function-style macros uniform with the
> use of ordinary functions in all contexts.
>
> Consider the following code sketch:
>
> ```
> if (<condition>)
>   foo(a);
> else
>   bar(a);
> ```
>
> where `foo` and `bar` are ordinary functions. Now imagine that you'd
> like to replace function `foo` with a macro of the above nature [named `CALL_FUNCS`]:
>
> ```
> if (<condition>)
>   CALL_FUNCS(a);
> else
>   bar(a);
> ```
>
> Now, if your macro is defined in accordance with the second approach
> (just `{` and `}`) the code will no longer compile, because the 'true'
> branch of `if` is now represented by a compound statement. And when you
> put a `;` after this compound statement, you finished the whole `if`
> statement, thus orphaning the `else` branch (hence the compilation error).
>
> One way to correct this problem is to remember not to put `;` after
> macro "invocations":
>
> ```
> if (<condition>)
>   CALL_FUNCS(a)
> else
>   bar(a);
> ```
>
> This will compile and work as expected, but this is not uniform. The
> more elegant solution is to make sure that macro expand into a regular
> statement, not into a compound one. One way to achieve that is to define
> the macro as follows:
>
> ```
> #define CALL_FUNCS(x) \
> do { \
>   func1(x); \
>   func2(x); \
>   func3(x); \
> } while (0)
> ```
>
> Now this code:
>
> ```
> if (<condition>)
>   CALL_FUNCS(a);
> else
>   bar(a);
> ```
>
> will compile without any problems.
>
> However, note the small but important difference between my definition
> of `CALL_FUNCS` and the first version in your message. I didn't put a
> `;` after `} while (0)`. Putting a `;` at the end of that definition
> would immediately defeat the entire point of using 'do/while' and make
> that macro pretty much equivalent to the compound-statement version.
>
> I don't know why the author of the code you quoted in your original
> message put this `;` after `while (0)`. In this form both variants are
> equivalent. The whole idea behind using 'do/while' version is not to
> include this final `;` into the macro (for the reasons that I explained
> above).

Comment: The original post was made by me in `comp.lang.c`. `bytes.com` apparently "appropriates" the content of `comp.lang.c` without making any references to the source.