# What happens if you declare a variable inside a macro?

Tags: c++, c

Suppose I have a macro defined as this:

```
#define FOO(x,y) \
do {
  int a,b;
  a = f(x);
  b = g(x);
  y = a+b;
} while (0)
```

When expanding the macro, does GCC "guarantee" any sort of uniqueness to a,b?  I mean in the sense that if I use FOO in the following manner:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
FOO(a,b);
```

After, preprocessing this will be:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
do {
  int a,b;
  a = f(a);
  b = g(b);
  b = a+b;
} while (0)
```

Can/will the compiler distinguish between the `a` outside the do{} and the `a` inside the do?  What tricks can I use to guarantee any sort of uniqueness (besides making the variables inside have a garbled name that makes it unlikely that someone else will use the same name)?

(Ideally functions would be more useful for this, but my particular circumstance doesn't permit that)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro

Comment: Don't use macros for things like that. We have functions for a reason.

Comment: @jleedev: Hygienic macros sound like a great idea...why hasn't gcc implemented this?  It sounds like the implementation would be simple straightforward.
@ThiefMaster:  Agreed that functions would be ideal for this, but they're out of the question because I can't add public functions for this purpose.

Comment: You can't write an exactly equivalent function, but you can write one the returns a+b rather than storing it in the y parameter. Why don't your circumstances allow that?

Comment: @R.D. gcc is a C compiler and implements what the C Standard specifies. It also implements some extensions, but these encourage people to write non-portable code; they should be avoided.

Comment: You have pretty much answered your own question. The code will indeed end up as in your second block and no it won't see the a and b outside so the a in f(a) and the b in g(b) are uninitialised variables. Pick variable names that do not meet your normal coding standard to avoid it. Something like MV_a MV_b.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yes a good reason to avoid macros but sometimes you want them, eg if you are going to optionally compile out the code.

Comment: @Cashcow You can of course optionally compile out the code in functions as well. No need to use macros for that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macros perform just string substitution. The semantic is low and the the compiler have a limited knowledge of the preprocessor (essentially #pragma which in fact is not a preprocessor keyword, and source line info).

In your case a and b are not initialized local value. Behavior is unpredictible.
Your expanded code is equivalent to the following one.

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
do {
  int a___,b___;
  a___ = f(a___);
  b___ = g(b___);
  b___ = a___+b___;
} while (0)
```

To avoid such case in c++ prefer the use of inline function or template.
If you use a c 1999 compliant compiler, you can use inline in c language.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function

In c you can make safer macro by defining longer variable and surrounding parameter by () :

```
#define FOO(x,y) \
do {
  int FOO__a,FOO__b;
  FOO__a = f(x);
  FOO__b = g(x);
  y = FOO__a+FOO__b + (y)*(y);
} while (0)
```

Note : I changed your example by adding a (y)*(y) to illustrate the case

It is also a good practice to use only once macro parameter.
This prevent side effects like that:

```
#define max(a,b) a>b?a:b
max(i++,--y)
```

Max will not return what you want.

Comment: In C, make a (inline) function. Don't use function-like macros ever.

Comment: But macros are usefule when conditional compilation is required.  An inline function gets called, and has it's parameters evaluated, which can be meaningless or a performance downer.  Never, suggests you never had to do a real world port of a significant system, between differing environments.

Comment: @Rob11311 That an inline function gets called and causes performance issues suggests that you are not using the correct compiler flags.

Answer (score 7):

If we consider scoping of variables, it is guaranteed that **a,b** inside the **do..while()** will be different from the ones defined outside.

For your case, the a,b defined outside will not exist inside the **do..while()**.

There are lots of things to watch out for when using MACROs.

Answer (score 4):

Variables a and b are treated just as any local variables inside a local scope.

The C language guarantees that if those variables happen to have the same names as outer scope variables, the local variables will be the ones updated.

Here is an example to illustrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO(x) \
{              \
  int a;       \
  a = x;       \
  printf("%d\n", a); \
}


int main()
{
  int a = 1;

  {
    int a = 2;

    printf("%d\n", a); // 2

    FOO(3); // 3

    printf("%d\n", a); // 2
  }

  printf("%d\n", a); // 1

  getchar();
}
```

Now, of course it might be a bright idea to *not* name every single variable in your program "a" just because C guarantees that local variables take precedence. But technically there is nothing stopping you from it.

Btw MISRA-C bans naming like this, it require each variable no matter scope to have an unique name, for readability and maintenance reasons.

(As a sidenote, function-like macros is incredibly poor programming style and shouldn't be used. Use real functions instead, and inline them if performance is critical.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no tricks other than garbling.  The C and C++ preprocessors do not have the equivalent of lisp gensym or hygienic macros.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no guarantee of uniqueness.

Infact, your code is about to fail.

Macros are just like replacement of text.

I usually use crazy variable names if I am inside a macro, like this:

```
#define FOO(x,y) \
do {
  int FOO_MACRO_a, FOO_MACRO_b;
  FOO_MACRO_a = f(x);
  FOO_MACRO_b = g(x);
  y = FOO_MACRO_a + FOO_MACRO_b;
} while (0)
```

Comment: Do you know how the namespace rules in C work? If you declare a local variable X and happen to have a variable also named X in another scope, your local variable will be the one that gets changed. There is absolutely no need to obfuscate the naming of your local variables. So the code is *not* about to fail, the only reason for naming local variables different than variables in outer scopes is readability.

Comment: @Lundin: Scoping and namespaces are separate things, please do not confuse the terminology.

Comment: @Chistopher Well... yes and no. "Scope" is a language nerd term used in the standards, while "namespace" is the term that the average programmer uses when speaking about programming on a generic level (language-independent). In the C language, namespaces aren't mentioned at all by the standard, so for a C programmer namespace and scope are the same thing. In C++ they are indeed entirely different things and shouldn't be mixed up.

Comment: @Lundin What is going to fail is `a = f(x);` when x happens to be the a from the outer scope. Expanding it to `a = f(a);` surely fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting gcc and/or g++ then you can use their special macro block feature:

```
#define max(x, y) ({ typeof(x) a_ = (x); \
                     typeof(y) b_ = (y); \
                     (a_ > b_) ? a_ : b_ })
```

This allows you to create unique local variables, very much the same as writing a function.

Of course, for portability, it's not recommended. On the other hand, if you only plan to work on systems that offer gcc/g++, it will work on all of those.

Source: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_3.html#SEC30

Further, with gcc / g++ you can use the `-Wshadow` command line option. In the event you inadvertently reuse a local variable with the same name, it will warn you. You can further use `-Werror` to transform those warnings in error. Now you can't compile if there is the possibility of a mixed up variable. You need to make sure to use a block, though. A do/while() as others have presented would do the job.

```
int a;

// code from macro;
do { int a = 5; ... } while(false);
```

With the combo I just described (`-Wshadow` + `-Werror`), you get an error when you do `int a = 5`.

Comment: No need for do while you can just do `some code {some code in block} some more code` without do while.

Comment: @TomerWolberg See chosen answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067226/c-multi-line-macro-do-while0-vs-scope-block — it's not _always_ required.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually make sure that regardless of what x and y are you won't have this problem by doing the following:

```
#define FOO(x,y) \
do\
{\
  int x##y##a,x##y##b;\
  x##y##a = f(x);\
  x##y##b = g(x);\
  y = x##y##a + x##y##b;\
} while (0)
```

By making sure a and b names contains x and y names you know they are different. But that's a really bad code and you probably shouldn't code like this.

Comment: Interesting suggestion! Yet there are still 2 potential problems: Unlike the original one, this new macro cannot be used with an expression as the first argument and you should remove the `;` at the end of the macro.

Comment: @chqrlie Your'e right, and I removed the `;`. And I'm afraid it's impossible to solve the first problem.

Comment: I guess one could use a single variable, namely an array of 2 ints, but I don't see a way to name it that is guaranteed not to clash with whatever `x` uses either. Naming it `y##y` makes it different from `y`, but `x` can be any name and or expression, hence can include any identifier. I agree with your conclusion: *the OP probably shouldn't code like this.*

Answer (score 0):

Macros are *textually* expanded as is, modulo parameter replacement, so there's nothing the compiler can do to provide the sort of guarantee you're asking for -- as you can see in the expansion, the `a` parameter will refer to the inner `a`, not the outer one. The solution is indeed to use "garbled" names, e.g. `int FOO_a, FOO_b;`

Answer (score 0):

In your macro that is indeed a danger and so is the possible reuse of `x` which is not guaranteed to be an l-value and could change by being used in the macro twice.

Even if you do need a macro, it can still be a light wrapper around an inline function, and one such that will take x and give you both `f(x)` and `g(x)` without possibly having to re-evaluate x would certainly be safe.

In your case something like:

```
template< typename T >
struct Foo
{
   T& x;

   explicit Foo(T&x_) : x(x_)
   {
   }   

   int f();
   int g();
};

template<typename T>
Foo<T> makeFoo(T& x)
{
     return Foo<T>(x);
}

#define FOO(x,y)
{
   Foo FOO_VAR(x);
   y = FOO_VAR.f() + FOO_VAR.g();
}
```

would be a safer way to do things. Of course if you don't need the macro at all, do away with it.