# How to invoke specific template method in children class (inheritance with CRTP - solution)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, methods, crtp

I have a Strategy like pattern, where Strategy interface is **IFilter**, Context is **Context** class, **Filter1**, **Filter2**... etc are Concrete Strategies, CommonFilter is interlayer between Strategy and Concrete Strategy for some service operations.

Inheritance structure **IFilter > CommonFilter > Specific_filters**

I have a lot of filter classes, each filter can work with different type of array of numeric data (int, int16, uint16, float, double ... etc). Filters differ from each other, but inside one filter they work equally on different numeric types.

Each filter receives at the input struct - **FilterMetaData**, which has: a data source, a data type and a data size. At the output, filter produces the same structure. **FilterMetaData apply(const FilterMetaData metaData);**
Filter can take e.g. uint16 data, and outputs uint16, for another filter in chain.

Filters have base class **CommonFilter** which validates **FilterMetaData**. CommonFilter implements an interface **IFilter**;

I have a list of filters **QList  m_filters;**
I want to iterate over filter objects like this

```
class Context {...

for(auto filter : m_filters)
    {
       filterMetaData = filter->apply(filterMetaData);//parse type of previous filter and work with it
    }
```

And I want that the data type of filter should be selected automatically from the field of the FilterMetaData :: typeOfData structure; So it should be a chain of filters. This chain would be invked multiple times;

**So I dont know how to call filter with specific type, i dont want to make type condition in each filter.**

p.s. im using old gcc 4.4.7 compiler compatible only with early c++0x

p.p.s added  specific filter example. So how can i automaticaly invoke **apply< T>** in specific filter based on numeric type. If a have Filter1, Filter2 ... FilterN. I dont want to check type in each filter, i want to make it once. All chain of filters must be called, one by one.
e.g.

```
data in/out    uint16 array       uint16 array      uint8 array  ...
--------->Filter1--------->Filter2--------->Filter3----->...
```

---

```
class IFilter
{
public:
    virtual ~IFilter(){}
    // do filtration
    virtual FilterMetaData apply(const FilterMetaData metaData) = 0;
};
```

---

```
enum TypeOfData
{
    Uint_8,
    Uint_16,
    Float
    ...
};

    class FilterMetaData
{
public:
    void *dataIn;
    TypeOfData typeOfData;
    int numOfElements;
};
```

---

```
class CommonFilter : public QObject, public IFilter
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(IFilter)
public:
    explicit CommonFilter(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public:

    virtual FilterMetaData apply(const FilterMetaData metaData) override = 0;
    const FilterMetaData metaData() const;

protected:
    bool applyMetaData(const FilterMetaData metaData);

private:
    FilterMetaData m_metaData;
```

### };

Example of filter

```
class Filter1 : public CommonFilter
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Filter1(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    //common type
    FilterMetaData apply(const FilterMetaData metaData) override;

    //filtration for specific type
    template<typename T>
    FilterMetaData apply(const FilterMetaData metaData);
};
```

Comment: There are no templates in the code you provided. If the implementation of your function is the same for each type of data, use templates. If the implementations differ for each data type, you can use template specializations, function overloading or a variation of Strategy pattern?

Comment: Thanks, I added some  more details in p.p.s section.  I can choose apply<T> only in specific class, for each filter, i want to check type once may be in base class. Or may be my architecture is wrong

Comment: It looks like you may want to do something with double dispatch.

Comment: Thanks, but i have same implementation in one filter for all types

Comment: Topic about [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this post ["Inheriting template methods" (Using CRTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703199/inheriting-template-methods)

I modified my code to match the CRTP pattern, now it works as I wanted.

Here is solution:

```
class IFilter
{
public:
    virtual ~IFilter(){}
    virtual FilterMetaData apply(const FilterMetaData metaData) = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(IFilter, "IFilter")
```

---

```
template<class T>
class CommonFilterTest : public IFilter
{
public:
    template<typename A = int>
    void doSomething(TypeOfData typeOfData)
    {
        qDebug() << "SomeClass doSomething";
        if(typeOfData == TypeOfData::Uint_16)
            static_cast<T*>(this)->doSomething<int>();
        else if(typeOfData == TypeOfData::Uint_8)
            static_cast<T*>(this)->doSomething<quint8>();
        else if(typeOfData == TypeOfData::Float)
            static_cast<T*>(this)->doSomething<float>();
    }

    // IFilter interface
public:
    virtual FilterMetaData apply(const FilterMetaData metaData) {}
};
```

---

```
class ConcreteFilter1 : public CommonFilterTest<ConcreteFilter1>
{
public:
    template<typename A>
    void doSomething()
    {
        float testNumber = 600.999;
        qDebug() << typeid(A).name() << "TheFirstType doSomething" << (A) testNumber;
    }

    FilterMetaData apply(const FilterMetaData metaData)
    {
        ((CommonFilterTest<ConcreteFilter1>*)this)->doSomething<int>(metaData.typeOfData);

        return metaData;
    }

};
```

---

Finaly execute:

```
    CommonFilterTest<ConcreteFilter1> * filter1 = new ConcreteFilter1();
    FilterMetaData metaData;
    metaData.typeOfData = TypeOfData::Uint_16;
    filter1->apply(metaData); // we can do it in loop for different filters
```