# C multi-line macro issue: why not use if(1){...} instead of do{...}while(0) in multi-line macro definition

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I want to invoke multi-line macro in circulation to break/continue it.

If I use "do{...}while(0)" in multi-line macro definition, break/continue is only effect on "do {...}while(0)", not the circulation who invoke this macro. So I consider using "if(1){...}" in multi-macro definition.

```
#define EXIT_CIRCULATION() \
        if(1){ \
           break; \
        }

void func(){
    while(1){
       ...
       EXIT_CIRCULATION();
       ...
    }
}
```

But I doubt wheather it is a good way to use "if(1){...}" in macro definition, because I can not find any example in internet.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067226/c-multi-line-macro-do-while0-vs-scope-block The first example itself is a reason not to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you code something like

```
 if (somecondition)
    EXIT_CIRCULATION();
 else
    break;
```

then the expansion of your macro won't behave as you intuitively expect. The `else` would apply to your `if (1)` and will never happen.

Comment: Won't it resolve to what you intuitively expect anyway because of the semicolon after the curly braces? If he wrote `#define EXIT_CIRCULATION() if(1) break`, I could see your point... (didn't try though, maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: But then my example won't even compile (mismatched `else`).

Comment: Oh, I see. Yup, I thought something else. Do ignore please.

Comment: But is there any way to resolve that exit circulation by invoke multi-line macro who use "do{...}while(0)". Thanks!

Comment: The explanation given in the answer is actually inaccurate. If you write something like that, the `;` after `EXIT_CIRCULATION()` will be seen as a standalone empty statement. Because of that it will *terminate* both `if`s. The `else` branch will be seen as an "orphaned" `else` and will produce a syntax error. It won't be attached to the inner "hidden" `if`, as this answer incorrectly claims. It will, again, produce a syntax error.

Comment: In fact, if the problem were with incorrect `else` association, then this definition would solve it `if (0); else { ... }`. This version does not suffer from the problem described in this answer. However, this "solution" will not work properly either. Only `do/while` does.

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea behind this trick is to find a way to create a multi-line (i.e compound)  statement that also incorporates a terminating `;` as its integral part. That will give you the opportunity to use `;` after your macro invocation without inadvertently introducing an empty statement.

The ordinary compound statement in `{ ... }` doesn't work because it does not end in `;`. The only multi-line statement in C/C++ that ends in `;` is `do/while`. There's no other statements in C/C++ grammar that would satisfy this requirement. (This is an inaccurate claim, see my "P.S." below)

In all other cases (including your `if (1) {...}`) the `;` after the macro invocation will be seen as an *additional independent standalone* empty statement. This will make it impossible to write a `;` after your macro invocation when it is used in contexts requiring exactly *one* statement (like true branch of `if-else` or the body of `do/while` cycle).

For example, if you define

```
#define A() if (1) {}
```

then this code will not compile

```
do
  A();
while (1);
```

because it will be replaced with

```
do
  if (1) {}; /* <- two statements, not one */
while (1);
```

and that is actually *two* statements between `do` and `while`. Specifying two statements between `do` and `while` without wrapping them into `{}` is syntax error.

**P.S. Correction:** The claim I make above about `do/while` being the *only* viable variant is incorrect . In @Michael Burr's answer you can see another suitable variant, which is using the `else ((void) 0)` trick for the same purpose. However, the main principle remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a macro that I believe will safely do what you want:

```
#define EXIT_CIRCULATION()  \
            if (1) {        \
                /* some statements */   \
                break;                  \
            }                           \
            else                        \
                do {} while (0)
```

The fact that the `if` here is matched with an `else` means that the macro is safe to use inside another `if`, and since the `else` clause is a do-nothing `do`/`while` statement that provides the similar properties to wrapping a multi-line macro in a `do`/`while`. Such as the macro will need to be terminated by a semicolon as if it were a normal statement; forgetting the semicolon will result in a syntax error. And it plays nice inside another `if` or `else` clause.

And most importantly for you (I think), the `break` statement isn't swallowed by the macro - it will break out the loop the macro is used in.

Whether that's a good idea or not is something else entirely.  Many programmers don't like flow-control statements to be hidden within a macro (unless the flow of control is entirely within the macro unit).

Here it is in action:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define EXIT_CIRCULATION()  \
            if (1) {        \
                puts("done.");          \
                break;                  \
            }                           \
            else                        \
                do {} while (0)

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (i  > 4)
            EXIT_CIRCULATION();
        else
            puts("working...");
    }

    printf("i == %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
working...
working...
working...
working...
working...
done.
i == 5
```