# what is the difference between "do { free(x); x = NULL; } while (0);" and "{ free(x); x = NULL; }"

Tags: c

```
#define FREE1(x) do { free(x); x = NULL; } while (0);
#define FREE2(x) { free(x); x = NULL; }
```

What is the difference between these macros?

Comment: no is not duplicated, it's a other question

Comment: Did you just post two identical questions?

Comment: @CarlNorum - The original question didn't include the braces around the second macro. If you look at the answers to that question, adding the braces may seem to fix the issue between the two macros.

Comment: indeed, It's not the same question. Please reopen it

Comment: Voted to reopen, but didn't the answers to your other question explain this sufficiently?

Comment: It's almost exactly the same.  Did you even try it out?

Comment: I tried and I get the same result but I'm not sure is the same code

Comment: It is an exact duplicate, but not of your original question. Here is [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1067226/335858). The linked question is also a duplicate, which is not surprising: this question gets asked a lot.

Comment: What kind of question is that? What is "what is the difference" supposed to mean? Is it like a game "find 10 differences"? The first macro begins with `d`, while the second one doesn't. Is this the answers you are looking for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your question is about the `do/while` trick in macros, there's no difference, because you apparently made an error in the first macro definition, which completely defeated the purpose of the trick. You put the `;` after the `whole (0)`. The proper implementation should absolutely *not* have the `;` after the `while (0)` in the first macro. This is the whole point of the `do/while` trick.

Now this code will not compile

```
if (condition)
  FREE2(arg);
else
  /* something else */;
```

This code will not compile either

```
do 
  FREE2(arg);
while (condition);
```

The point of the `do/while` technique is to make this code compile. But it will not compile with your `FREE1` macro either because of the aforementioned error.

However, if you define the first macro correctly

```
#define FREE1(x) do { free(x); x = NULL; } while (0)
// No `;` at the end!!!
```

then the first macro will work perfectly fine in the above code samples. This is actually the reason people use the `do/while` technique in multi-statement macros - to make it work correctly and uniformly with ordinary functions in such contexts.

P.S. As a side note, the purpose of all such techniques is to turn a group of *multiple* statements into one compound statement. In your specific case the `free(x); x = NULL;` sequence can be re-implemented as a *single* expression `(free(x), x = NULL)`, which eliminates the need for any multi-statement macro techniques, i.e. this

```
#define FREE3(x) (free(x), x = NULL)
```

will work as well. But it is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there's no difference, C-wise.

The reason is you included a trailing semi-colon in:

```
#define FREE1(x) do { free(x); x = NULL; } while (0);
```

The reason you usually want to use `do...while(0)` is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros), is that you generally want to use it in `if...else` blocks:

```
if (...)
    FREE(x);
else
   ...
```

But with the above usage and macros this:

```
if (...)
   do { free(x); x = NULL; } while (0);;
else
   ...
```

...and...

```
if (...)
    { free(x); x = NULL; };
else
    ...
```

...are both ill-formed.

Comment: besides the syntactic reasons that you mentioned, the `do...while(0)` construct is usually used to allow usage of `break` from inside the block to avoid `goto` and/or code refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

Both are half-baked attempts to fix the semicolon issue discussed in [Do-While and if-else statements in C/C++ macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154138/367273).

A better way to define this macro is

```
#define FREE3(x) do { free(x); x = NULL; } while (0)
```

(without the trailing semicolon.)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
#define FREE1(x) do { free(x); x = NULL; } while (0);
```

Gets executed just once, so it's the same as:

```
#define FREE2(x) { free(x); x = NULL; }
```

But in the assembly code there is a more branch.Even if a modern compiler would probably optimize it, so with all the probabilities even the assembly code generated will be the same.