# Standard macro wrapper for NSAssert(false, ...)?

Tags: objective-c, assert, foundation

Most of the assertions I write are based on a conditional expression, like so:

- NSParameterAssert(**key != nil**);
- NSAssert(**count <= MAX_FACTOR_COUNT**, @"Too many factors");
- NSAssert1(**size % 2 == 1**, @"Cannot create hexagonal board with even size %i", size);

But I also have quite a few cases of triggering an assertion failure with a hard-coded *false* value:

- NSAssert(**false**, @"Abstract method invoked");
- NSAssert(**false**, @"Unimplemented");
- NSAssert(**false**, @"Invalid operation for this subclass");

This feels wrong to me. I feel like I should be saying something like this instead:

- NSAssertFail(@"Abstract method invoked");
- NSAssertFail(@"Unimplemented");
- NSAssertFail(@"Invalid operation for this subclass");

My question is:  How have people traditionally dealt with this?  What do you name a preprocessor macro that wraps `NSAssert(false, ...)`?

Is `NSAssertFail()` a good name?

Comment: Just `#define NSAssertFail(x) do { NSAssert(0, x); } while(0)`

Comment: I was thinking just `#define NSAssertFail(x) NSAssert(0,x)`. What magic does the `do`...`while(0)` add?

Comment: It creates an inner scope.  It's a good idea to do it for any macros that call methods, especially with arguments, and usually gets optimized away.

Comment: Ok, I can see that helping with certain types of macros. Does it make a difference in this case? Just wanna make sure I'm not missing something. A related question: how is `do { foo(...); } while(0)` different from `{ foo(...); }`?

Comment: Here, this is a better explanation than I could ever give: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067226/c-multi-line-macro-do-while0-vs-scope-block

Comment: @CodeFi but the `NSAssert` macro is already wrapped in one.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I still do it (mostly out of habit).  And it's not like  `do { do { NSAssert(0, x); } while(0); } while(0);` does anything exceptionally weird.

Comment: @CodaFi you never know! It could loop out of fear the programmer is incompetent. (The code sucks and it doesn't want to run it anymore, so it give up and loops)

Comment: @ColeJohnson We have standards bodies that prevent that kind of thing from happening.  C isn't Java.

Comment: @CodaFi they aren't required completely in a sense. GCC claims C++11 support just because some of it is.