# Simulating scope in C macros

Tags: c, macros, scope

I have the following macro to print out the contents of an array of integers for debug purposes:

```
#define PRINT_ARRAY(ary, num)        \
    int ai = 0;                      \
    printf("{");                     \
    for(ai=0; ai < num; ++ai) {      \
        printf("%d", ary[ai]);       \
        if(ai < num-1) printf(", "); \
    }                                \
    printf("}\n");
```

The problem I am having is that when I use it more than once, some compilers complain that I am redefining `ai`.

Is there a way to make the identifier different for each invocation of the macro? I can come up with a naming scheme that would have a very low change of name collisions, but I'd like to make it automatic.

I know I could use a function, but I am still curious, since I would like to know if there is a way to do this with macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put it into it's own scope, e.g. surround it with `{` and `}`

Like this:

```
#define PRINT_ARRAY(ary, num)        \
{                                \
    int ai = 0;                      \
    printf("{");                     \
    for(ai=0; ai < (num); ++ai) {      \
        printf("%d", ary[ai]);       \
        if(ai < (num)-1) printf(", "); \
    }                                \
    printf("}\n");                   \
}
```

I also added parantheses around the num parameter, so you can use a complex expression without having strange sideffects.

WRT to your identifier naming:

You can use macro expansion to change the name using a parameter, but as there are not counter or loop constructs in all c preprocessors I know, I don't think it's possible to automatically change the identifier after every user. Another way would be to have the macro redefine itself every time, but afaik that's also not possible.

Edit:

As has been pointed out (thanks to Aaron McDaid, also see the link he posteed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1067238/146041), you should use a `do {` `} while(0)` construct around your code, so your macro would become:

```
#define PRINT_ARRAY(ary, num)        \
do {                                \
    int ai = 0;                      \
    printf("{");                     \
    for(ai=0; ai < (num); ++ai) {      \
        printf("%d", ary[ai]);       \
        if(ai < (num)-1) printf(", "); \
    }                                \
    printf("}\n");                   \
} while(0)
```

Comment: `do { ... } while(0)` should be used with multi-statement macros, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1067238/146041

Comment: You should always use do..while(0) when using macros.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use a classic do-while trick? For example:

```
#define FOO(EXPR) \
  do { \
    (EXPR); \
  } while(0)
```

Comment: For more information on why `do {...} while(0)` should always be used with multi statement macros, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1067238/146041

Answer (score 2):

If your C is C99-compliant, put `ai`'s declaration in the `for` loop's header. You should also surround the code with `do / while(0)`

```
#define PRINT_ARRAY(ary, num)        \
    do {printf("{");                     \
    for(int ai=0; ai < num; ++ai) {      \
        printf("%d", ary[ai]);       \
        if(ai < num-1) printf(", "); \
    }                                \
    printf("}\n"); } while(0)
```

so that it could be used after control structures without surrounding it with curly braces.

Comment: Delete the trailing `;` !

Comment: In either case, it should be put inside a `do {...} while(0)`.  The first macro would be incorrect immediately after a `if(...)`, for example.