# Sort 3 numbers using macros [C]

Tags: c, sorting, macros

Lets say we have defined macro SWAP:

```
#define SWAP(a,b) {\
int tmp = a; \
   a = b; \
   b = tmp;}\
```

and using SWAP we need to sort 3 numbers (just write another macro which uses macro called SWAP):

```
#define SORT(a,b,c) \
    (a > b) ? SWAP(a,b) : ((a > c) ? SWAP(a,c) : ((b>c) : SWAP(b,c)))
```

I wrote it like this but my code shows only some errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(a,b) {\
int tmp = a; \
   a = b; \
   b = tmp;}\

#define SORT(a,b,c) \
    (a > b) ? SWAP(a,b) : ((a > c) ? SWAP(a,c) : ((b>c) : SWAP(b,c)))

int main()
{
    int a = 1024, b =  7, c = 11;

    printf("a = %d b = %d\n", a, b);
    SWAP(a,b)
    printf("a = %d b = %d\n", a, b);

    printf("a = %d b = %d c = %d\n", a, b);
    SORT(a,b,c)
    printf("a = %d b = %d c = %d\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

errors I get:

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token|
```

Comment: What line is the error on?  Errors come from specific lines.

Comment: compile with -E option which writes source with pre-processor output

Comment: You can't have *blocks* (i.e. brace-enclosed statements like `{ int tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp; }`) inside of *expressions* (groups of operators and other expressions which get evaluated into a value, like `x ? y : z`.  It's just not allowed by the C language.  If you convert your use of the ternary operator into a `if/else` statement, it should work fine, although I'd advise you strongly not to ever write a sorting function with macros like that.

Answer (score 3):

Let's expand your SORT(a,b,c) macro:

```
(a > b) ? SWAP(a,b) : ((a > c) ? SWAP(a,c) : ((b>c) : SWAP(b,c)))
```

Expanding each SWAP(a,b):

```
(a > b) ? {
int tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;
} : ((a > c) ? {
int tmp = a;
a = c;
c = tmp;
} : ((b>c) : {
int tmp = b;
b = c;
c = tmp;
}))
```

This is not valid C code. That's why it fails to compile.

Define it like this:

```
#define SORT(a,b,c) \
    if(a > b) { SWAP(a,b) } else if(a > c) { SWAP(a,c) } else if (b>c) { SWAP(b,c) }
```

BTW, it's a good practice, to define multiline macros using dummy do-while loops (see: [C multi-line macro: do/while(0) vs scope block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067226/c-multi-line-macro-do-while0-vs-scope-block) ):

```
#define SWAP(a,b) do {\
int tmp = a; \
   a = b; \
   b = tmp;} while(0)\
```

This way, you can write it like a regular function call:

```
SWAP(a,b);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! But can I do it without else if but only by using the `?` operator?

Comment: No, because the ?: operator expects rvalue's. A block {...} is not an rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

On compiling with gcc -E the SORT macro was expanded like this

```
 (a > b) ? {int tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp;} : ((a > c) ? {int tmp = a; a = c; c = tmp;} : ((b>c) : {int tmp = b; b = c; c = tmp;}))
```

The problem here are the braces and the semi colon in the SWAP function.

Answer (score 0):

@Tamas Zahola
you need to modify

```
#define SORT(a,b,c) \
 if(a > b) { SWAP(a,b) } else if(a > c) { SWAP(a,c) } else if (b>c) { SWAP(b,c) }
```

this will not work if value of b will be greater then c in whole program.