# multi-expression macro's in C

Tags: c, macros

```
#define SWAP(a,b) { a^=b ; b^=a ; a^=b; }

if (x < 0)
         SWAP(x,y);
else
         SWAP(y,x);
```

My code given above doesn't work.  It gives the following error while compiling.

```
trial.c:3:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'if'
trial.c:5:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'else'
```

I am trying to figure out the exact reason why it is not working.  The preprocessor expands the macro as follows

```
if (x < 0)
         { 
           x^=y ; 
           y^=x ; 
           x^=y ; 
         }; 
else
         { 
           y^=x ; 
           x^=y ; 
           y^=x ; 
         };
```

I have a suspicion that the semi-colon at the end of curly braces is causing the problem.  But I am not sure.  Can someone explain?

Comment: The `;` after the ending `}` of your `if` and `else` statements shouldn't be there

Comment: I know how to do it :) I want an explanation on why the above would not work.

Comment: see if..else..'s syntax.

Comment: Do you expect `SWAP(x,y)` and `SWAP(y,x)` to do different things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C multi-line macro: do/while(0) vs scope block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067226/c-multi-line-macro-do-while0-vs-scope-block). "Now, if your macro is defined in accordance with the second approach (just '{' and '}') the code will no longer compile, because the 'true' branch of 'if' is now represented by a compound statement. And when you put a ';' after this compound statement, you finished the whole 'if' statement, thus orphaning the 'else' branch (hence the compilation error)."

Comment: @KeithThompson - No it doesn't but that is beside the point. :)

Comment: Beware `SWAP(A[i++],B[j++])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a  macro that expands to a *statement*, the do/while(0) trick is the way to go.

But it's more flexible, when possible, to have a macro that expands to an *expression*. If you want to use it in a statement context, just add a semicolon:

```
#define SWAP(a, b) ( (a)^=(b), (b)^=(a), (a)^=(b) )
```

The problem with your original macro, or rather with the way you were using it, is that the added semicolon creates an extra statement. The syntax of an `if`-`else` statement is

`if (`*expression* `)` *statement* `else` *statement*

By providing both a block `{ ... }` and a semicolon, you have *two* statements between the `if` and the `else`.

The do/while(0) trick solves the semicolon problem. Writing a macro that expands to an expression (which is not always possible) avoids it altogether.

Some more observations:

You seem to be expecting `SWAP(x, y)` and `SWAP(y, x)` to do different things. They should behave identically.

The xor hack does let you swap to variables without using a temporary, but 99% of the time it makes more sense just to use a temporary. One problem with using a temporary is that you have to declare it, which means you have to know the type; that's not always possible. A drawback of the xor hack is that if the two operands are the same object (say, `arr[i]` and `arr[j]`, where `i ==j`), it doesn't work. And it only works for integers.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a suspicion that the semi-colon at the end of curly braces is causing the problem

That's exactly right! If you put a semicolon after a block with curly braces, that would be a new, empty, statement after the `if`. The compiler will parse it like this:

```
if (x < 0) // The "if"
         { // The body of the "if"
           x^=y ; 
           y^=x ; 
           x^=y ; 
         }
;    // <<== An empty statement after the one-sided "if"
else // <<== A "stray" else (syntax error)
```

This is the common trap with macros: if you want to use curly braces in your macro, use the `do / while(0)` trick (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257425/335858)):

```
#define SWAP(a,b) do { a^=b ; b^=a ; a^=b; } while (0)
```

Note: I hope this is a learning exercise, because there is no difference between swapping `A` with `B` and swapping `B` with `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a semicolon is not legal at this point. `if(condition) { ... };` is not a well-formed `if` statement, which is either `if(condition) { ... }` or `if(condition) statement;`

A classical trick is to wrap the macro contents as a `do { contents } while(0)`. In this case, a semicolon is expected directly following a macro invocation, which thus feels like a function.

It then expands to

```
if (x < 0)
    do { a^=b ; b^=a ; a^=b; } while (0);
```

Which is a valid form of an `if` expression: `if(condition) statement;`

Comment: Can you please elaborate a semi-colon is not legal at this point?