# Assignment macro writing

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write a macro for the following repeated code inside the for loop.

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
 a->x = b->x;
 a->y = b->y;
 a->z = b->z;
}
for(j=0;j<n;j++){
 a->x = c->x;
 a->y = c->y;
 a->z = c->z;
}

---------
with macro
#define COPY(x,y,z) \
a->x = x;\
a->y = y;\
a->z = z;\

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 COPY(b->x,b->y,b->z);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 COPY(c->x,c->y,c->z);
```

I keep getting the error unexpected expression before ;

---

thanks for quick responses,
Looks like I am more inclined to a function call rather macros, as it might get cumbersome overtime.
Are there any performance impacts than using a function call rather than a macro?

Comment: `COPY(x,y,z)`  --> `COPY(p,q,r)`

Comment: Even if you fix the compilation error, only the first line of the macro is actually inside the loop.

Comment: @interjay , yeah but that's easily fixed, just put it in a block { }

Comment: @Guiroux It's not that easy. Using a `{}` block will lead to other problems. You need something like the `do/while(0)` idiom to solve it properly. But there will still be other issues with using macros like the argument being evaluated multiple times.

Comment: @interjay i don't say you are wrong but when you say "will lead to other problems" you could explain why ?

Comment: @Guiroux http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros

Comment: Why do you perform the 3 assigments `n`-times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am trying to write a macro for the following repeated code inside the for loop.

Please don't. It is just 3 lines. All you will do is to clutter down your code with obscure and unsafe home-brewed language syntax. You've already managed to write one fatal bug by doing so: not using  {} for the macro. Function-like macros are very bad practice in most cases.

First of all, is there a reason why you can't write `*a = *b;` ?

If there is such a reason, then instead consider doing something like this:

```
typedef struct // given this struct
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
} xyz_t;

void xyz_copy (xyz_t* dest, const xyz_t* source)
{
  dest->x = source->x;
  dest->y = source->y;
  dest->z = source->z;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a bad case for macros. You might try

```
#define COPYxyz(Dst,Src) do {   \
    (Dst)->x = (Src)->x;        \
    (Dst)->y = (Src)->y;        \
    (Dst)->z = (Src)->z;        \
   } while(0)
```

(notice that the `do{`...`}while(0)`  is a very old [useful trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1067238/841108) in macros)

then code `COPYxyz(a,b)` (but `COPYxyz(p++,--q)` or `COPYxyz(++p,p)` is a disaster, this is why coding such a macro is bad)

However, if you have

```
  struct my_st  {int x, int y, int z};
  struct my_st *a = something();
  struct my_st *b = otherthing();
```

you could just code a structure assignment:

```
     *a = *b;
```

or, assuming you are sure that `a` and `b` do not alias (are not the same address) and do not overlap, you could

```
     memcpy(a, b, sizeof(struct my_st));
```

and if the structure contains more than `x`, `y`, `z` fields but you only want to copy  them, make a proper [inline function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function):

```
static inline void copy_xyz(struct my_st*dst, const struct my_st*src) {
   assert (src != NULL);
   assert (dst != NULL);
   if (dst == src) return;
   dst->x = src->x;
   dst->y = src->y;
   dst->z = src->z;
   /// remaining fields are not copied!
}
```

Then you'll code `copy_xyz(p++,p)` without fears, and it should be as efficient as the `COPYxyz` macro. You might remove the `assert`-s and the `if  (dst == src) return;` if you are sure they are useless.

Comment: why do ? but yeah, the left and right operand of -> gestion was totally wrong, so at least you fixed that

Answer (score 0):

```
#define COPY(x,y,z) \
a->x = x;\
a->y = y;\
a->z = z;
```

with this when you pass

```
COPY(b->x,b->y,b->z);
```

Then you have

```
a->b->x = b->x;
a->b->y = b->y;
a->c->y = c->y;;
```

Which is not what you need.
So you need to replace it with

```
#define COPY(p,q,r) do{\
a->x = p;\
a->y = q;\
a->z = r;\
}while(0)
```

Comment: You forgot the } brace.

Answer (score 0):

The macro

```
#define COPY(x,y,z) \
a->x = x;\
...
```

will replace `x` both for both occurences in `a->x = x;`, e.g. 
`COPY(b->x, ...)` gives `a->b->x = b->x`, so use other names for the macro parameters.

---

Notice that

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 COPY(b->x,b->y,b->z);
```

will expand to

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  a->x = b->x;
a->y = b->y;
a->z = b->z;
```

which is not what you intend. Make it a habbit to always put macro bodies within `do { ... } while (0)`.

Answer (score 0):

This definition:

```
#define COPY(x,y,z) \
a->x = x;\
a->y = y;\
a->z = z;\
```

With a for loop

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    COPY(b->x,b->y,b->z);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    COPY(c->x,c->y,c->z);
```

Which results in this quick test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COPY(x,y,z) \
    a->x = x;\
    a->y = y;\
    a->z = z;\

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        COPY(b->x,b->y,b->z);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        COPY(c->x,c->y,c->z);
}
```

Only pre-processed with: `gcc -E main.c > main.i`

Gives

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        a->b->x = b->x; a->b->y = b->y; a->b->z = b->z;;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        a->c->x = c->x; a->c->y = c->y; a->c->z = c->z;;
}
```

There's a lot wrong!

You have two places where macro replacement's ocurring in `a->x = x` because both x's get replaced, so firstly change to unique identifiers. Secondly, do not encode the copy-to element in the define. In your case this is a, make this something passed to the macro:

```
#define COPY( dest, x_copy, y_copy, z_copy ) \
    dest->x = x_copy; \
    dest->y = y_copy; \
    dest->z = z_copy;
```

You've also fallen into the trap of having if followed by a multiple-statement macro which will obviously not perform how you intended because you've not surrounded the multi-line macro with curly braces! It's common practice to wrap multiple line macros in `do{ } while(0)` so that they can be used as you would expect:

```
#define COPY( dest, x_copy, y_copy, z_copy ) \
    do { \
    dest->x = x_copy; \
    dest->y = y_copy; \
    dest->z = z_copy; \
    } while(0)
```

Now, replacing your macro which this new one results in an output we'd expect to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COPY( dest, x_copy, y_copy, z_copy ) \
    do { \
    dest->x = x_copy; \
    dest->y = y_copy; \
    dest->z = z_copy; \
    } while(0)

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        COPY(a, b->x,b->y,b->z);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        COPY(a, c->x,c->y,c->z);
}
```

Again, `gcc -E main.c > main.i` results in the correct code expanded from the macro:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        do { a->x = b->x; a->y = b->y; a->z = b->z; } while(0);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        do { a->x = c->x; a->y = c->y; a->z = c->z; } while(0);
}
```