# Simple #define:d macro doesn't work in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm doing an introductory course to C programming, and we've just started defining macros. I'm supposed to define the macro **CHECK** that prints **msg** (a string) if **cond** is false, however, it doesn't print the **msg** to the **stdout** stream, whether **cond** is true or false. Any ideas?

```
1     #define CHECK(cond, msg) if(!cond) fprintf(stdout, "%s", msg)
```

Comment: Please give us the code you **call** this macro.

Comment: I'd bet you are passing it something like `CHECK(a == b, "a is not b");`, right? in which case that will expand to `if (!a == b)`, and then operator precedence ruins your day… that's why you **always unconditionally parenthesize** all your macro arguments.

Comment: maybe take cond in parenthesis `#define CHECK(cond, msg) if(!(cond)) fprintf(stdout, "%s", msg)`

Comment: Your macro definition doesn't work because the line starts with a `1`. See http://sscce.org for how to ask a “my program doesn't work” question.

Comment: Is it possible that you're missing the `\n` at the end?

Comment: Thank you @TheParamagneticCroissant, makes complete sense but didn't come to think of that.

Comment: Also, just don't write macros that change control flow in a unexpected way. Your macro is flawed in multiple ways.

Comment: @Adrian hopefully this makes you prefer functions to macros enough so that after completing this task, you won't make macros where an (inline) function would do.

Answer (score 8):

You should wrap your function-like macro like this:

```c
#define CHECK(cond, msg)                   \
    do {                                   \
        if (!(cond)) {                     \
             fprintf(stdout, "%s", msg);   \
        }                                  \
    } while (0)
```

Explanation:
[C multi-line macro: do/while(0) vs scope block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067226/c-multi-line-macro-do-while0-vs-scope-block)

Comment: Nearly perfect. Just wrap any occurencies of `cond` and `msg` in parentheses: `(cond) ... (msg)`

Comment: You are right, thanks! I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping it in {}:

```
 #define CHECK(cond, msg) {if(!cond) fprintf(stdout, "%s", msg)}
```

plus , make sure you really don't start with '1'

Comment: This will lead to surprising behavior: `if (x) CHECK(cond, msg); else func();` won't work because of the extra semicolon.  You have to use `do { ... } while (0)`.