# Using ({...}) in a #define vs. do {...} while(0);?

Tags: c, macros

Are there any disadvantages to using the former syntax? It seems cleaner and clearer than the latter.

Comment: That is a GCC extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067226/c-multi-line-macro-do-while0-vs-scope-block

Comment: @JonnyHenly see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros

Comment: Simple answer: do not use macros unless there is no other way. Do not use them out of laziness. Taken *ad infinitum* you will be using them to write your own language.

Comment: Note that the `do ... while` version of the `#define` **should not** end with a semicolon: the semicolon will be provided by the usage of the macro (as in `if (a != b) MACROCALL(a, b); /* semicolon here */`)

Answer (score 0):

`({…})`, as BLUEPIXY wrote, is a GCC extension, and as such has the disadvantage of being not portable to different compilers, while the syntax `do {…} while(0)` is standard.