# String handling inside Preprocessor macro

Tags: c, string, parameter-passing, c-preprocessor, stringification

I need to change a implementation of Macro(LOGGING_MACRO)
printf into syslog.

**Macro Usage :**

```
LOGGING_MACRO(5,("Value of x,y=%d,%d\n",x,y));
```

**Def1 :**

```
#define LOGGING_MACRO(loglevel,str) printf str;
```

**Def2 :**

```
#define LOGGING_MACRO(loglevel,str) syslog(loglevel,str);
```

***Note :*** I cannot change the macro format :(

Def2 throws error as syslog will not accept 'str'(2nd arg) with front & back braces. [But working fine in Def1 with printf ]

Kindly suggest how to remove the 1st & last braces from 'str' inside the macro before passing 'str' to syslog.

Comment: Give an example how you call your macro, because this approach `printf str;` is completelly failed.

Comment: @tilz0R that is given in the section "Macro Usage :"

Comment: Hello DYZ . Paranthesis is passed when calling the Macro.

Comment: This is not possible what you are asking directly, but if you use local variable then it can be done. Edit: No, it can't. You failed your usage.

Comment: Any other ways i can edit content of 'str' inside a macro ???

Comment: No. You could do this with extern variable for example, but this won't work in every situation properly. When you declared your macro you weren't thinking a bit about loglevel parameter in printf. If you would need to include it, you could see your usage limitation.

Comment: If you define a `printf`-like function (say, `char *foo(const char *format,...)` that takes a format string and all additional parameters and returns a formatted string, then you can `#define LOGGING_MACRO(loglevel,str) syslog(loglevel,foo str);`

Comment: @DYZ: This can work as I thought too, but it won't allow you multitasking environment. You need then mutex for loggin function.

Comment: @tilz0R So what? Isn't `printf` using mutex, too?

Comment: @DYZ You think your implementation is thread safe?

Comment: @tilz0R My implementation of the macro is as thread-safe as the implementation of `foo()`.

Comment: @DYZ I do agree with you. Check my answer about thread safe implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example below will work in single thread application:

```
char* custom_log(const char *fmt, ...) {
    static char outputString[200]; //Adjust your size for maximal log value
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf(outputString, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    return outputString;
}
```

Then modify your macro to:

```
#define LOGGING_MACRO(loglevel,str) syslog(loglevel, custom_log str)
```

Remember, this works only in single-thread mode and make sure, `custom_log` function is visible where custom_log function is called.

For multi-thread, you might update it like this:

```
#define LOGGING_MACRO(loglevel,str) do {\
    mutex_lock(); /*Lock your mutex for debug print*/ \
    syslog(loglevel, custom_log str); /*Debug*/ \
    mutex_unlock(); /*Unlock mutex*/ \
} while (0)
```

Keep in mind that you have to write `mutex_lock` and `mutex_unlock` functions for your requirements in your system to lock only debug functions between multi threads.

Comment: What's the while loop, for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067226/c-multi-line-macro-do-while0-vs-scope-block

Comment: Ya . Its Working fine . Thank you .