# How to handle error: expected expression before ‘do’ when there is no "do"?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, alsa

I get the following compiler error, even though there is no "do" expression in my code.

```
gcc -Wall -g -c main.c -lasound
In file included from /usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h:49:0,
                 from main.c:2:
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:8:5: error: expected expression before ‘do’
  if(snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params) < 0) {
     ^
main.c:6:30: warning: unused variable ‘params’ [-Wunused-variable]
         snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
                              ^~~~~~
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

From the following minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{       
        snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;

        if(snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params) < 0) {
                return 0;
        }

        exit(0);
}
```

I'm aware this is not a valid ALSA program. I'm also aware that it appears snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca() doesn't even return anything worthwhile to check for errors against? That's not relevant though, this should valid C code regardless, even if it abuses the API.

Where is the "do" expression? If I go to /usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h and poke around there, I don't see anything obvious that would indicate a problem.

If I remove the conditional if test, and get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;

        snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

        exit(0);
}
```

This will compile with no errors.

What is this?

If I look in pcm.h, I see:

```
#define snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(ptr) __snd_alloca(ptr, snd_pcm_hw_params)
int snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc(snd_pcm_hw_params_t **ptr);
void snd_pcm_hw_params_free(snd_pcm_hw_params_t *obj);
void snd_pcm_hw_params_copy(snd_pcm_hw_params_t *dst, const snd_pcm_hw_params_t *src);
```

However, this doesn't tell me anything. Why does the compiler produce this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm also aware that it appears snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca() doesn't even return anything worthwhile to check for errors against? That's not relevant though, this should valid C code regardless, even if it abuses the API.

No, if `snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca()` does not have a value you cannot compare it against 0. For example, the following is also invalid:

```
void func(void) { }
void other(void) {
    if (func() < 0) { // Error
    }
}
```

In reality, `snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca()` is a macro, and it’s a wrapper for another macro, `__snd_alloca`. The `do` is there to make it behave more like a statement. You can only call it as a statement on its own line, or anywhere else where a `do` loop is legal.

```
snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
```

You cannot check for errors because `alloca()` does not check for errors. If `alloca()` fails, it will just stomp on your stack, and bad things will happen. You can’t do anything about it, except not use `alloca()` (this is why you might hear advice to avoid alloca).

For an explanation of why the `do` loop is used, see: [C multi-line macro: do/while(0) vs scope block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067226/c-multi-line-macro-do-while0-vs-scope-block)

For more information about how `alloca()` works, see: [Why is the use of alloca() not considered good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-the-use-of-alloca-not-considered-good-practice)