# Wonder about some #define tricks

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

While reading codes of my group project, I come across many DEFINEs, and some of them seems strange. To generalize it, please look at the following 2 examples.

Example 1:

```
#define SNPRINTF(dst, fmt, arg...)  snprintf(dst, sizeof(dst), fmt, ##arg)
```

what does "##" means in this circumstance? I've tried to delete both of them, and write codes like "char buf[1024]; SNPRINTF(buf,"%s,%s","abcd","efg");" which produced the same result. So "##" seems no use and no harm to me.

Example 2:

```
#define CLOSE(fd)   do  {   \
        if (-1 != (fd)) {   \
                    close(fd);  \
                    (fd)    = -1;   \
                }   \
} while (0)
```

Necessary to stuff the inner code to the `do{}while(0)` statement? What's the use?

Comment: The do...while question has been answered before. I'll try to dig up a link.

Comment: Found just the ## part of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025858/what-does-mean-for-the-c-preprocessor

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829930/multi-statement-macros-in-c/1830046#1830046 discusses the `do while` matter, but I know there is question separate question out there. Here they are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067226/c-multi-line-macro-do-while0-vs-scope-block-closed maybe others

Comment: @dmckee thanks for the valuable link! How do you "dig up"? Just by memory, or the site provides us some useful tools besides tags?

Comment: The search has some operators described here http://stackoverflow.com/search but mostly I dug through pages of search results. That's easier to stomach when you *know* the answer is there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `...` identify a [variadic macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro) per the C99 standard.  The token to indicate expansion of "all remaining argument" in the right hand side, per the standard, is `__VA_ARGS__` -- I imagine you're using some C compiler with a non-standard extension that allows the different forms you're using (`##` is the preprocessor token-pasting operator, but I don't see how that applies here).

The second form is a classic trick (older even than C89) to ensure a `;` after the macro behaves correctly, an `else` after it doesn't bind to the wrong `if`, and so on.  Basically, wrapping the multiple and conditional statements needed in that `do`...`while` safely "nests" them inside a block that requires a semicolon afterwards, syntactically "just as if" the macro invocation was instead a function call.

Comment: the `args...`  and `##args` combination is a GCC preprocessor extension, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Answer (score 3):

Two answer your questions in order:

1. ### is the pasting operator, and so its not really doing anything there. I *think* (couldn't find any references) that there are non-standard versions of it that will eat a preceding comma if its empty, so maybe that's what this is for.
2. As already mentioned, the `do{...}while(0)` thing is a standard trick to ensure that whatever gets pasted into the `...` can be treated as a single statement. It generally lets you write things like:

```
if( floon )
  CLOSE(floon);
```

without worrying about it.