# can #define be used for printing information?

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I came across a statement which I didn’t understand. Can anyone explain me please.
It is a C++ program to sort data.

```
#define PRINT(DATA,N) for(int i=0; i<N; i++) { cout<<"["<<i<<"]"<<DATA[i]<<endl; } cout<<endl;
```

And also when I tried to rearrange the statement in the below format,I got compilation error!

```
#define PRINT(DATA,N)
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
   cout<<"["<<i<<"]"<<DATA[i]<<endl;
}
cout<<endl;
```

Comment: You need to tell it that the next line is part of it if you're going to split them up.

Comment: @neodev Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281368/multi-line-define-directives

Comment: There is no reason to use a macro. A function should be used. The type of data could be a template parameter if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be used if you properly define it. **But** .... just because *it can be used*, does **not** mean that it should be used.

Use `std::copy_n`:

```
std::copy_n(data, n, std::stream_iterator<X>(std::cout, " "));
```

That will print all the `n` items from `data` to the stdout, each separated by a space. Note that in the above code, `X` is the type of `data[i]`.

Or write a proper *function* (**not** *macro*) to print in your own defined format. Preferably a function template with `begin` and `end` as function parameters. Have a look at how algorithms from the Standard library work and are implemented. That will help you to come up with a good generic design of your code. Explore and experiment with the library generic functions!

Comment: Yup, definitely a better solution. It can be easily adapted to match the format.

Answer (score 4):

1. It's a macro, each time you write PRINT(DATA,N) the pre-processor will substitute it for the entire for loop, including the variables.
2. You're missing \ signs at the end of each line. This tells it the Macro continues to the next line. (Look at [Multi-statement Macros in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829930/multi-statement-macros-in-c)
3. If you use macro, use brackets around any variables (DATA) and (N). The substitution is literal and this will allow usages like PRINT(data, x+1) which otherwise cause unexpected results.
4. Don't use macro unless you REALLY must, there are many problems that can arise from this, it doesn't have a scope and so on. You can write an inline method or use std::copy_n like Nawaz proposed

Comment: Sure. I really can't stress enough how you should try to avoid using macros unless you must. Think what would happen if you write something like PRINT(Data, x++). You expect the ++ will only occur once, when it fact it'll happen every time N is used in the macro.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you want to use a macro for.

Write a template function that does the exact same thing:

```
template<typename T>
void PRINT(const T &data, size_t n){
    for (size_t i=0;i<n;++i)
        cout << "["<<i<<"]"<<data[i]<<endl;
}
```

You should really avoid using macros. The only reason I find you NEED macros is when you need to use the name of the input (as string), or location (**LINE** or **FILE**) e.g.:

```
#define OUT(x) #x<<"="<<x<<"; "
#define DEB std::cerr<<"In "<<__FILE__<<":"<<__LINE__<<": "
```

for use in printing like this:

```
DEB << OUT(i)<<OUT(val[i])<<OUT(some_func(val[i],3))<<endl;
```

Which will print

```
In file.cc:153: i=4; val[i]=10; some_func(val[i],3)=4.32;
```

This is a functionality you can't do without macros. Anything you CAN do without macros you SHOULD