# Why do I keep seeing multiline macros wrapped in (seemingly) pointless loops?

Tags: c, loops, macros, while-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how does do{} while(0) work in macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766827/how-does-do-while0-work-in-macro)

Example from [this](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/phk/thetoolsweworkwith.html) blog post:

```
#define VTAILQ_INSERT_BEFORE(listelm, elm, field) do {              \
    (elm)->field.vtqe_prev = (listelm)->field.vtqe_prev;            \
    VTAILQ_NEXT((elm), field) = (listelm);                          \
    *(listelm)->field.vtqe_prev = (elm);                            \
    (listelm)->field.vtqe_prev = &VTAILQ_NEXT((elm), field);        \
} while (0)
```

I've come across others, but this one highlights what I mean well enough

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long story short:

If you use a non looped macro in an unbraced if else statement, you will get screwed.

```
if (a)
    VTAILQ_INSERT_BEFORE(c, d, e);
else
    blah(b);
```

Would break terribly in this case.

More detailed answer here:

[Why use apparently meaningless do-while and if-else statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-mac)