# What is the use of do{}while(0)?

Tags: c++, python, c, semantics, do-while

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there sometimes meaningless do/while and if/else statements in C/C++ macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-mac)
>   [What's the use of do while(0) when we define a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro)
>   [how does do{} while(0) work in macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766827/how-does-do-while0-work-in-macro)

I wonder what the use `do{ ... } while(0)` (`...` as a place-holder for other code) is, as it would, as far as I know, be exactly the same as just using `...`.

You can find code like this in the official *CPython* source. As an example, the `Py_DECREF` macro:

```
#define Py_DECREF(op)                                   \
    do {                                                \
        if (_Py_DEC_REFTOTAL  _Py_REF_DEBUG_COMMA       \
        --((PyObject*)(op))->ob_refcnt != 0)            \
            _Py_CHECK_REFCNT(op)                        \
        else                                            \
        _Py_Dealloc((PyObject *)(op));                  \
    } while (0)
```

Comment: In general it lets you use `break` or `continue` to skip the remaining code without using `goto` or `return` (returning from the function completely). In your example the purpose is very different -- it forces the user to follow uses of the macro with a `;` without causing any compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes compiler require `;` so the macro looks like a function call:

```
Py_DECREF(x); // ok
Py_DECREF(x) // error
```