# What is the intention of following function?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I found following function in a device driver code.

```
static void module_exit(void)
{
        do { } while (0);
}
```

my question is why they used `do { } while (0);` inside this function. They can simply return from there instead of calling this `do { } while (0);`. Is there any special reason for having `do { } while (0);` here?

Comment: It looks like "leftover junk". The (empty) loop will immediately terminate on the first while-condition check, if it isn't optimized away entirely. Now, if there was *actual* code in the loop (and perhaps outside), then it could use `break` or `continue` as a form of flow-control ..

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766827/how-does-do-while0-work-in-macro

Comment: An optimizing compiler might even optimize the whole loop away.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special reason to use do while, normally in a module_exit has clean up functions  will un-register drivers. Do while will exit in your case. While(0) is like false case and will fall out of loop immediately .