# Why does Linux have so much "dummy" code?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the use of do while(0) when we define a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro)

When I'm reading through Linux kernel code, the header files often have `#define` blocks that look like (from `include/linux/wait.h` in 2.6.37):

```
#define init_waitqueue_head(q)  \
    do {                        \
        ...                     \
    } while (0)
```

What is the purpose of the `do...while` sequence when the "loop" will only ever execute once?  It makes sense that a programmer would want to open up a new scope for temporary variables, but that doesn't require the `do...while` to exist.  Is it just syntactic sugar, or does it help the compiler in some way?

Similarly, I've seen lines of code with an `if` statement that looks like (from `include/linux/kfifo.h`):

```
#define kfifo_put(fifo, val) \
    ...                      \
    if (0) {                 \
        ...                  \
    }
```

Also in a `#define`, again why not just remove that tidbit instead of having it never run?  I'll note that in the `kfifo_put` define the scoping is started with `{` and ends with `}` without a `do...while` loop.

Comment: See: [Why are there sometimes meaningless do-while and if-else statements in C macros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macr)

Comment: The `if (0) { ... }`: these are still compiled and can throw compilation errors. In this case it's a compile-time check for some property of the types of the parameters passed.