# Macro scope guards

Tags: c, macros

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why are there sometimes meaningless do/while and if/else statements in C/C++ macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macr)
>   [What's the use of do while(0) when we define a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro)

Is there a difference between

```
#define MACRO(x)  \
    {             \
    ...           \
    }
```

and

```
#define MACRO(x)   \
    do {           \
    ...            \
    } while(0)
```

?

Comment: Is there a way for asker to close?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that question specifically asks why do {} while(0) but doesn't compare it to {} which looks cleaner and you might otherwise use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do { ... } while(0) allows the macro to be used in conditional code.

Looks like this question has been asked before: [C multi-line macro: do/while(0) vs scope block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067226/c-multi-line-macro-do-while0-vs-scope-block)

[Here's another link](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/DoWhile0) to a couple of reasons to do so, and why to omit the semicolon at the end.

Comment: if you see a duplicate please close it if you have the reputation or if not flag it

Answer (score 1):

Well, the second feels more natural since it always requires a semicolon after using it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT RE-EDITED**

in literature I can remember always the form `do {..} while(0)` (sometimes even with the ;, but this form proved to be wrong). Since macros are literal substitution, it is easy to imagine that there's a difference when `{ }` is allowed but `do { } while(0)` is not, or when you need the MACRO behaves like a "statement" (`{ };` do not, while `do { } while(0);` does; an example is the case of if / else( if):

```
   if (COND)
   {          // MACRO(..);         
      ...  
   };
   else
   {      // this is an else without if
   }
```

while

```
   if (COND)
     do {        // MACRO(..);
      ...
     } while(0);
   else
   {
     // this work properly
   }
```

So the first has a void statement that syntactically makes impossible to "join" the else to its if, while the second form is correct (and if the macro has the final ; as I remembered to have seen somewhere, the same error of the first form occurs)

Comment: They are different - try putting an else after the if

Comment: whop, right, my first "impression" was more right than the second thought. Going to re-fix it