# Whats meaning of this rsAssert macro?

Tags: c++, c, macros

i found this code [from here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/frameworks/base/libs/rs/rsUtils.h)

```
#if 1
#define rsAssert(v) do {if(!(v)) LOGE("rsAssert failed: %s, in %s at %i", #v, __FILE__, __LINE__);} while(0)
#else
#define rsAssert(v) while(0)
#endif
```

**Question 1:**

Here i am not getting why `do and while` is used here? Is there any special reason for using this?

**Question 2:**

What is the purpose of doing this all in macro. Why just one dont use `assert()`  ?

i think perhaps there is a valid reason for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The do/while is a well-known trick for turning a block of statements into something that syntactically acts like a single statement. It allows use in places like:

```
if (whatever)
    rsAssert(whatever);
else
    // ...
```

whereas, most alternatives would produce a syntax error in this case.

As for why using it at all: because it writes output with `LOGE` instead of printing to `stderr`, and (unless LOGE does so) this doesn't seem to abort the program like `assert` will.

Answer (score 3):

Your first question about why there's a do/while "loop" is covered here: [What's the use of do while(0) when we define a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro)

The answer to the second question could be better answered by the code's author, but I guess they wanted to use their own logging system when an assert failed rather than the default one.

Answer (score 0):

As asked many times before, the reason a do-while loop is use is for syntactic sugar:

```
// this line would be valid if a simple if was used:
rsAssert(myAssert)

// with a do-while, however, this is now invalid:
rsAssert(myAssert)

// so, that means you have to add the ';' to make it look like a function call:
rsAssert(myAssert);
```