# Grouping in C macros

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do-While and if-else statements in C/C++ macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros)
>   [What’s the use of do while(0) when we define a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro)

I often see a code like this:

```
#define foo() do { xxx; yyy; zzz; } while (0)
```

Why do-while wrapper is used here? Why not simply

```
#define foo() { xxx; yyy; zzz; }
```

?

EDIT : removed semicolon.

Comment: I bet you rather see `#define foo() do { xxx; yyy; zzz; } while (0)` (without the trailing semi-colon - that's exactly why...)

Comment: search for `[c]while (0)` in the SO search bar, you'll get piles of answers to this.

Comment: He is asking why are they not simply writing `{}` rather than `do{}while(0)`. So this is _not_ a duplicate and the link doesn't answer the question! Voting to reopen.

Comment: Link from other post does answer the question: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Swallowing-the-Semicolon.html

Comment: @Lundin - See the answer (link) from user:raghava on that other post.

Comment: @mcl No, that doesn't answer why you can't simply type {}.

Comment: @WilliamPursell No, we just had the question re-opened since that link does not answer why you can't simply type {} instead of do{}while(0).

Comment: @Lundin  The 4th code block of the accepted answer addresses that portion of the question.

Comment: The excellent comp.lang.c FAQ is [here](http://www.c-faq.com/). You've just asked question 10.4.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Ah right, there we have it then.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simple answer.

```
#define foo() do { xxx; yyy; zzz; } while (0)
#define foo() { xxx; yyy; zzz; }
```

---

```
if (condition)
    foo();
else
    x++;
```

When you use the do-while version, that will get correctly expanded to:

```
if (condition)
    do { xxx; yyy; zzz; } while (0);
else
    x++;
```

When you use the {} version, that will get expanded to this, which is a syntax error (no matching `if` for the `else`). *Note the extra semicolon in the second line.*

```
if (condition3)
    { xxx; yyy; zzz; };
else
    x++;
```