# Fragment code from libbb.h file

Tags: gcc, memory-barriers

I have some trouble to understand the usage of optimization barrier code in the following sequence:

```
   struct globals;
/* '*const' ptr makes gcc optimize code much better.
 * Magic prevents ptr_to_globals from going into rodata.
 * If you want to assign a value, use SET_PTR_TO_GLOBALS(x) */
extern struct globals *const ptr_to_globals;
/* At least gcc 3.4.6 on mipsel system needs optimization barrier */
#define barrier() __asm__ __volatile__("":::"memory")
#define SET_PTR_TO_GLOBALS(x) do { \
    (*(struct globals**)&ptr_to_globals) = (void*)(x); \
    barrier(); \
} while (0)
```

Is this something necessary becaause of the "while (0) condition?

Answer (score 0):

The while(0) is just syntactic sugar and has no impact on optimization.  See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro) for why it is there.  The barrier is likely there to prevent the compiler from moving loads/stores upwards over SET_PTR_TO_GLOBALS, which it might otherwise be tempted to do since under normal rules for C, the assignment to a const variable can't have any effect.