# c Macro with multiple optional arguments

Tags: c, printf, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to write a debug print macro that will print the function name with the option of including format/varargs to print the parameters as well.

I've set up my modules so that each has it's on print color by adding a style variable to the individual modules and using it in my print macro.

The working print macro is as follows

```
//myprint.h
...
#define STYLE_UNDERLINE "\033[4m"
#define STYLE_NORMAL    "\033[0m"

#define STYLE_BLUE      "\033[0;34m"
... // more colo(u)rs here

#define PRINTF(fmt, ...) printf("%s" fmt STYLE_NORMAL, style, ##__VA_ARGS__)
...
```

Usage:

```
//myfile.c
...
static char * style = STYLE_BLUE;

void myFunc(int i) {
    PRINTF("String with no params\n");
    PRINTF("i value %d\n", i);
}
```

I'd like to do something similar with a PRINT_FN macro that would be used as follows

```
//myfile.c
...

void myFunc(int i) {
    PRINT_FN();       // just print the function name
    // equivalent to
    PRINTF("%s%s()", STYLE_UNDERLINE, __func__);

    PRINT_FN("%d", i) // print the function name and parameter
    // equivalent to
    PRINTF("%s%s(%d)", STYLE_UNDERLINE, __func__, i);
}
```

I can figure out a macro that almost accomplishes this, the problem being that it requires you to minimally send an empty format string.

```
#define PRINT_FN(fmt, ...) printf("%s" STYLE_UNDERLINE "%s(" fmt ")" STYLE_NORMAL, \
                                  style, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Is there a way I can also make the fmt parameter optional?

Comment: I'd just like to get down to calling it as PRINT_FN() rather than PRINT_FN("")

Comment: Makes no sense. It won't print you a newline.

Comment: @n.m. I can't make sense of your comment. Are you suggesting all print statements require newline's? In the end I added a newline to my PRINT_FN macro but certainly not to PRINTF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to cram everything into one `printf`. Separate the adornments and the actual output:

```
#define PRINT_FN(...)                                   \
    do {                                                \
        printf("%s%s: ", STYLE_UNDERLINE, __func__);    \
        printf("" __VA_ARGS__);                         \
        printf("%s\n", STYLE_NORMAL);                   \
    } while (0)
```

Concatenating an empty string leads to an empty string if the format is empty or to the original format otherwise. gcc's `-Wall` setting warns about an empty format string, however.

The `do ... while` shold be compiled away and serves to make the macro [behave as one statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro). Maybe overkill in yor case, but still.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, use `snprintf` for the `__VA_ARGS__` and then print out the complete line with one `printf`.

Comment: Is the `##` is still needed before `__VA_ARGS__`?

Comment: @user3817250: No, but the macro works only if the first argument, if any, is a string literal, but that's the common case for `printf`-like functions. (Some compilers even warn you if you don't specify a string literal.) The gcc extension `, ##__VA_ARGS` suppresses the comma if the variadic argument list is empty, but we want string concatenation here.