# Is the if - else redundant in this macro?

Tags: c++, qt

This is a follow up to this question:

[What's the use of do while(0) when we define a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro)

This macro is used in the Qt unit tests:

```
#define QVERIFY2(statement, description) \
do {\
    if (statement) {\
        if (!QTest::qVerify(true, #statement, (description), __FILE__, __LINE__))\
            return;\
    } else {\
        if (!QTest::qVerify(false, #statement, (description), __FILE__, __LINE__))\
            return;\
    }\
} while (0)
```

It verifies the statement, and if it is false it produces an error message with the given description.

My question is, what could be the reason for the `if` - `else` statement inside? Why isn't it defined simply like this?

```
#define QVERIFY2(statement, description) \
do {\
    if (!QTest::qVerify(statement, #statement, (description), __FILE__, __LINE__))\
        return;\
    }\
} while (0)
```

I suspect that the explaination is of the same sort as in the refered question. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

To give some more context, the following variant of the macro, without the description, is also defined:

```
#define QVERIFY(statement) \
do {\
    if (!QTest::qVerify((statement), #statement, "", __FILE__, __LINE__))\
        return;\
} while (0)
```

This would suggest, that the trick somehow concerned with the `description` parameter.

Comment: Based solely on what you have posted, the shorter version should work as well as the longer version.

Comment: Probably to improve clarity. This way we know that `statement` is a boolean (`if(statement)`), otherwise we couldn't be sure `qVerify(statement..`, without looking at `qVerify` definition

Comment: One thing that macro does is ensure that `statement` is evaluated before `description`.

Comment: @rici it also ensures that `description` is evaluated whichever way the branch goes.

Comment: @1nflktd, I thought the same, but could have just done `if (!QTest::qVerify((statement) != 0, ...`

Comment: @rici Nice insight. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `description` would be evaluated by the suggested simpler call, too. Just not in order.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is historical thing (I didn't found history earlier then qt4.5 so I'm no sure). Probably somewhere in the past there was no else statement and this "if" prevented evaluation of description. Then someone decided that passed verification should also be processed and added else statement.

Comment: @MarekR Seems unlikely because of the alternative macro in the simpler form.

Comment: @rici I suggest that the `if` is for the reason you state, and the `else` is for the reason I state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible explanation is that the macro ensures that `statement` is evaluated before `description`.

Comment: This is indeed the only difference between the two.

Comment: Now if I think about it, wouldn't the `statement` be evaluated before the `description` anyways? Or is the order of evaluation of the function parameters undefined?

Comment: @GáborAngyal I believe the proper term is *unspecified*. It's basically left to the compiler writers to do it in the order they find easiest or fastest.

Answer (score 1):

An important difference, if `QTest::qVerify`'s first parameter has type `bool`, is that there are more types that are *contextually convertible* to `bool` than there are that are *implicitly convertible* to `bool`.

Given

```
struct S { explicit operator bool(); } s;
void f(bool);
```

the call `f(s)` is invalid, but `if (s) f(true); else f(false);` is valid.

However, given the definition `QVERIFY` macro you show in the question, it does seem likely that this was never a real consideration.

Comment: This is also a good answer, but I think the other is a stronger argument.