# Macro - expression is not assignable

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I get this error when compiling:

```
macro.c:11:2: error: expression is not assignable
    ProdottoAumentato(10, 20);
```

I don't know why it says this, I can't find any errors.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ProdottoAumentato(X, Y)    X++; X * Y;

int main(void) {

    ProdottoAumentato(10, 20);

    printf("\nEnd\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Whatv are you _actually_ trying to achieve ? (See [XY Question](http://xyproblem.info/)). Or in other words what is the call to `ProdottoAumentato(10, 20);` supposed to do ?

Comment: It's supposed to increment the X value by 1 and then multiply that value with Y.

Comment: Why use the increment operator at all!? `((X + 1) * Y)`

Comment: I'm guessing you don't understand the exercise.

Comment: _It's supposed to increment the X value by 1 and then multiply that value with Y_: but there is no `X` neither `Y` in your program.

Comment: Your macro produces `10++; 10 * 20;` which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 7):

Macros perform textual replacement. So `ProdottoAumentato(10, 20);` gets replaced with the following:

```
10++; 10 * 20;;
```

`10++` is not valid. You can't modify a literal, which is what the error message "expression is not assignable" is referring to.

> How can I increment that value then?

You need to assign the value to a variable to modify it. See Vittorio Romeo's answer for an example of this.

Answer (score 5):

Macro is *not* a function by any stretch of imagination. `X` in the macro is textually substituted with the first parameter of the macro; same is done for `Y` - it is replaced with the second parameter.

The expression `10++` is invalid, for the same reason that `10 = 10+1` is invalid. However, this is the expression that you get after macro expansion, which is what the compiler tells you by its "expression is not assignable" error.

Comment: Got it, thank you. How can I increment that value then?

Comment: @Andr1x Pass something that can be `++`-ed, e.g. a variable: `int val=10; ProdottoAumentato(val, 20);` will do the trick: `val` will be `11` upon return.

Answer (score 2):

Replying to Andr1x's comment:

> How can I increment that value then?

You could use a function:

```
int ProdottoAumentato(int* x, int y)
{
    ++(*x);
    return (*x) * y;
}
```

Which can be called as follows:

```
int my_x = 10;
int res = ProdottoAumentato(&my_x, 20);
assert(my_x == 11);
assert(res == 11 * 20);
```

---

> I can't. It's an exercise for university, I'm required to do everything in a macro.

That's sad, because this is a terrible use case for a macro. Nevertheless, if you want to use a macro, your arguments must evaluate to symbols which are "incrementable" *(i.e. lvalues)*.

Here's the "safest" way of doing this with a macro:

```
#define ProdottoAumentato(result, X, Y) \ 
    do { ++(X); result = (X) * (Y); } while(0)
```

Then you can call:

```
int my_x = 10;
int res;
ProdottoAumentato(res, my_x, 20);
assert(my_x == 11);
assert(res == 11 * 20);
```

Which will be preprocessed to:

```
int my_x = 10;
int res; 
do { ++(my_x); res = (my_x) * (20); } while(0);
assert(my_x == 11);
assert(res == 11 * 20);
```

*([Why am I using `do while`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro))*

Comment: I can't. It's an exercise for university, I'm required to do everything in a macro.

Comment: @Andr1x: updated my answer, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain what you really want and why you are (incorrectly) using a macro. I'm guessing that it is because you think that macros run faster.

Then just define an `inline` function like

```
static inline int ProdottoAumentato(int x, int y) 
  { return (x+1)*y; }
```

with most [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (e.g. `gcc -Wall -O2` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....),  this is as fast as your attempted macro, because the compiler will do [inline expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion).

If for some strange reason you still want to use macro and the C preprocessor, check its output, e.g. by running `gcc -C -E yourcode.c > yourcode.i` then look (with a pager like `less` or some source code editor) into the generated `yourcode.i` containing the preprocessed form.

As a rule of thumb, you generally need to add extra parenthesis in macro definitions:

```
#define ProdottoAumentato(X,Y) ((X)+1)*(Y))
```

otherwise `ProdottaAumentato(u+3,v+5)` won't be expanded like you wish, since the preprocessing is a purely textual operation.

You might also use [statement exprs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) (a useful GCC extension) and have

```
#define ProdottoAumentato(X,Y) ({int _x = (X); int _y = (Y); (++_x * _y)})
```

You might define two *global* variables; `int xx, yy;` and have

```
#define ProdottoAumentato(X,Y) ((xx=(X),((yy=(Y)),((++xx)*yy))
```

using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately it's a very, very weird exercises I got from my teacher that had to be done just with use of a macro and no functions whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You want is

```
#define ProdottoAumentato(X, Y) ((X)++, (X) * (Y))

int main(void)
{
  int x = 10;

  x = ProdottoAumentato(x, 20);

  /* x is 220 here. */
}
```

Before the actual C compilation, the pre-processor converts the above source code into:

```
int main(void)
{
  int x = 10;

  x = ((x)++, (x) * (20));


}
```

This

```
  ((x)++, (x) * (20))
```

are two expressions sequenced by the comma operator. First the left side is evaluated (with a sequence point), then the right side. The latter value is "returned" as the result of the whole expression.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want this macro to do? You are performing operations over constants and the results are not attributed to any variable.

If you just want to take two numbers, add one to the first and multiply by the second, you should try

```
#define ProdottoAumentato(X, Y) (X+1)*Y
```

If, on other hand you want to increment a variable, and multiply it by another variable you should try

```
#define ProdottoAumentato(X, Y) X++; Y*=X
```

And that will never work with constants like you tried to pull.