# Macro to do fgets stripping newline

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Given the following two statements to use `fgets` and strip the newline:

```
puts("Enter the name.");
fgets(temp.name, 40, stdin);
temp.name[strcspn(temp.name, "\n")] = 0;
```

Is the following macro sufficient to take the place of this?

```
#define FGETS(str, len)  fgets(str, len, stdin); str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0
FGETS(temp.name, 40);
```

Are there any deficiencies or ways it can be improved?

Comment: wrap it in `do {} while (0)`, so no one is tempted to do something like `FGETS(temp.name, 40) + 1;`

Comment: If you're also hard-coding `stdin`, I wouldn't call it `FGETS`, personally. But yeah, that's fine. Also, what @EugeneSh. said.

Comment: The biggest deficiency is the lack of error checking / EOF handling.

Comment: @user3386109 what would be an example where this might fail and need to be error-checked?

Comment: Don't abuse the preprocessor like this.  If you want the functionality, write a function.

Comment: @carl.hiass Curious, why a macro and not a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, I do the `do { } while (0);` trick.

But, if you want a macro that is a drop in replacement for `fgets` where you can test the return value transparently, how about:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FGETS(_buf,_len,_xf) \
    ({ \
        char *_cp = fgets(_buf,_len,_xf); \
        if (_cp != NULL) \
            _buf[strcspn(_buf,"\n")] = 0; \
        _cp; \
    })

#define FGETOF(_buf,_xf) \
    FGETS(_buf,sizeof(_buf),_xf)

int
main(void)
{
    char buf[100];

    while (1) {
        if (FGETOF(buf,stdin) == NULL)
            break;
        printf("buf: '%s'\n",buf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

The multiline macro is fine, but can be cleaned up [with no loss in speed] using an `inline` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static inline char *
xfgets(char *buf,size_t siz,FILE *xf)
{
    char *cp;

    cp = fgets(buf,siz,xf);

    if (cp != NULL)
        buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")] = 0;

    return cp;
}

#define FGETS(_buf,_len,_xf) \
    xfgets(_buf,_len,_xf)

#define FGETOF(_buf,_xf) \
    FGETS(_buf,sizeof(_buf),_xf)

int
main(void)
{
    char buf[100];

    while (1) {
        if (FGETOF(buf,stdin) == NULL)
            break;
        printf("buf: '%s'\n",buf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you do two macros for `FGETS`...`FGETOF` instead of just one?

Comment: It's [only] a nicety. The direct replacement is the `FGETS` macro. (e.g.) In `main`, we could do: `if (FGETS(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin) == NULL)`. But, using `sizeof(buf)` is common, so under the DRY [don't repeat yourself] principle, I added the `FGETOF` to _force_ the common usage of `sizeof(buf)` for the length. YMMV

Comment: Similarly, I use a `#define ALLOCME(_ptr) _ptr = malloc(sizeof(*_ptr))` to eliminate some repetitive boilerplate. Sometimes, I have this macro call `xmalloc` [which I define], that calls `malloc` but checks the return value and aborts on `NULL`, since 99.44% of the time you want to abort if `malloc` fails.

Comment: `FGETOF(buf,stdin) == NULL` looks like it using a C extension to get a return value from the macro.  I like the idea of returning something to help detect EOF - using standard code. Hmmm.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, so that's why I did the inline function version as a choice.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica As to the extra error checking, I'd leave that out of `FGETS` but one could add several different wrapper macros in the `FGETOF` vein, to do extended checking. Personally, I've rarely needed to differentiate an error from EOF for simple programs like we have. But, to do that, my preference would be to put that in the helper function rather than the macro body. For EOF, we just want to stop the loop. For an error, the remedy would depend upon the context. For most simple cases, it would be `perror` and `exit`. So, we define an extra macro implementing the policy we want.

Comment: @CraigEstey Agree that a fuller input handling strains the limits of sensible macro coding.

Answer (score 3):

File input/output is a back-hole of time.  Little to gain using a macro over a clean function.

Perhaps a function to do the prompt too?

Code uses a leading size per [C2x priciple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features).

```
char *getaline(int size, char *s, const char *prompt) {
  if (prompt) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
  }
  if (fgets(s, size, stdin)) {
    // Perhaps add detection of failing to read the whole line?

    s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';
    return s;
  }
  if (size > 0) {
    *s = '\0';
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I think we're on the same page. Your function is similar to ones I wrote for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65011769/check-if-all-values-entered-into-char-array-are-numerical/65013419#65013419

Comment: @chux -- thanks, I just think there's one typo on the line `if (size > 0) [` should be `{`.

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks:

- When a macro is composed with several instructions, it is preferable to surround it with "do { ... } while(0)" to be able to use it in "if" statements without brackets, prevent some arithmetic operations on the macros...
- The parameters of the macros must be surrounded by parenthesis as they may not be simple variables but some expressions;
- fgets() returns NULL if EOF is entered or upon error;

Hence the following proposition:

```c
#define FGETS(str, len) do {  if (fgets((str), (len), stdin) != NULL) (str)[strcspn((str), "\n")] = 0; else (str)[0] = '\0'; } while(0)
```

Then you can use it as:

```
if (expression)
  FGETS(str, len);
else
  do_something_else;
...
FGETS(buf + 34, LEN);
```

**N.B.**: This [page](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/c_preprocessor.html) provides lots of tips to make secured macros.

Comment: Lost  ready ability to distinguish 1) line of input like `"\n"`, 2)  end-of-file, 3) input beginning with a _null chracter_ and 4) input error.   Further code could check for _some_ of these condition when `str[0]==0`.

Comment: Minor: `strcspn(str, "\n")` --> `strcspn((str), "\n")`

Answer (score 1):

```
#define READLINE(str, len) do { if(fgets((str), (len), stdin) != NULL) { (str)[strcspn((str), "\n")] = 0; } else { /*TODO: Handle error*/ } } while (0)
```

Notice, I specifically renamed it from `FGETS` because it has hard-coded `stdin` as the "file" part.  In my mind it's misleading to call it `FGETS`. Also, added brackets to arguments ([pretty much a must for macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820340/the-need-for-parentheses-in-macros-in-c)), wrapped it in a `do - while(0)` ([here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687569/c-do-while0))  and a basic framework for handling errors.

Comment: "Handle error" here includes "handle end-of-file", something not usually considered an error.