# C macro parameter test at design time

Tags: c, macros

I need a macro variable check at design time (preprocesor), more specific that number to fit in 24 bits.
The macro is intended to be used in a if() statement so I have no idea how to test it.

This is a ARM systick timer (24 bits) and so many time I forgot to #define the right value, especially when change the MCU clock and of course, my if() never fired and this silly mistake was hard to debug.

So in this example, there is a trick to force gcc to ERROR when PARAMETER > 24 bits ?

```
    #define PARAMETER   20000000  // over 24 bits, should throw a error at design time
    #define MyMacro(var, par)       (var > par)

    uint32_t variable;

    if(MyMacro(variable,PARAMETER))
    {
        // do something
        //  do something WRONG because PARAMETER > 24 bits


        // Actually this is working as expected, test for < is valid because 
// _Static_assert() is check for TRUE condition
// But I am still trying to find a way to combine this in original macro
        _Static_assert(PARAMETER < 0xFFFFFF, "Ooopss... ERROR");

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want a compile error in case that value is too large?

Comment: exact, I am trying to use _Static_assert() but no luck so far :)

Comment: I'm not getting it, if `MyMacro` was a function, how would you write this function?

Comment: See my answer and let me know if it is helpful

Comment: no, the macro is intended to be used in a regular if() statement like I said

Comment: Oh, unfortunately a variable's value is unknown at compilation time..

Comment: Unless your check is intended to raise an error in case the maximum _potential_ value doesn't fit three bytes. E.g.: uint16 is ok, uint32 is not.

Comment: _"// This is working, but I am trying to combine inside macro  "_: please show that

Comment: @orfruit with your `_static_assert` you don't use `variable` but with `MyMacro` you use `variable`. I'm not getting it. Please explain what exactly `MyMacro(variable,PARAMETER)` is supposed to do.

Comment: hmm.. nope, it works only with pure constants, if I use PARAMETER from macro is not :((( ughh.. quite complicated !

Comment: I've tried to extend my answer.

Comment: @Roberto Caboni, I just tested and is working at DESIGN time as expected, please see edited. I am still trying to combine in original macro, however, I don't want to reply to my own answer. Thanks for effort.

Comment: @orfruit I confess it is not clear to me. Ps: feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: _Static_assert() is part of C11+ and is checking for TRUE at COMPILE (or DESIGN) time, has nothing to do with runtime. Please feel free to test my code. The problem is that I couldn't find a way to have it in if() statement

Comment: Yes, but if statement is executed **at runtime**. PS: did you downvote my answer?

Comment: No, of course I didn't,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `_Static_assert` is syntactically defined as a declaration, which means you can't use it directly inside of an expression.

However, `_Static_assert` isn't needed anyway, because you can perfectly (sans the nice compile time error reporting--but you're a programmer, you should be able to figure out a compile time failure a slightly more technical compile-time error message) emulate it with

```
#define static_assert_0expr(Truth) ((int)(0*sizeof(struct { int _ : (Truth)?1:-1; })))
```

(or an equivalent) and that you can fit in an expression (even an integer constant expression) no problem:

```
#define static_assert_0expr(Truth) ((int)(0*sizeof(struct { int _ : (Truth)?1:-1; })))

#define PARAMETER   20000000  // over 24 bits, should throw a error at design time
#define MyMacro(var, par)       (static_assert_0expr((par)<0xffffff) + ((var) > (par)))

//or this, but this is won't preserve integer-constant expressions because of the comma:
/*#define MyMacro(var, par)       (static_assert_0expr((par)<0xffffff), ((var) > (par)))*/
//alternatively: (static_assert_0expr(assertion) ? (expr) : (expr)) is the most
//general form (though it leads to larger preprocessor expansions, which may worsen debugging experience with cc -E)

#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
    static_assert_0expr(1)+1;
    uint32_t variable;

    if(MyMacro(variable,PARAMETER))
    {
    }
}
```

The above `static_assert_0expr` macro could also be implemented with `_Static_assert`:

```
#define static_assert_0expr(Truth) \
   ((int)(0*sizeof(struct { int _; _Static_assert(Truth,""); })))
```

or you could paste the body of this directly in `MyMacro` and customize the message (but I consider `_Static_assert` and its custom compile-time error message feature an unnecessary addition to C and prefer not to use it).

Comment: I accepted yours because you pointed me to the right direction :) thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't want to reply my own answer, but I think I found a solution that is working (thanks @PSkoicik) and thanks to GCC that allows statement expressions (found in this reply)
[Using and returning output in C macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532621/using-and-returning-output-in-c-macro)

So basically **I could use** _Static_assert() inside if() statement, with a helper macro

```
#define CheckParameter(val) ({bool retval = true; _Static_assert((val)< 0xFFFFFF, "Timer value too large!"); retval;})
```

Now my macro become

```
#define MyMacro(var, par)       ((var > par) && CheckParameter(par))
```

Which should work because CheckParameter() will always return TRUE at RUNTIME but at COMPILE time, _Static_assert() will catch my error parameter.

So now I can use

```
if(MyMacro(variable,PARAMETER))
{
// PAREMETER will be in range
}
```

Hope I'm not missing something :)

Comment: Expressions statements (i.e., putting () around a compound statement (block)) are a common extension, but they're not technically standard C. They're also not usable at filescope (unless gcc devs grant me my wish: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93239)  and inside integer constant expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check that `PARAMETER` is > 24 bits during compile time you can simply do this:

```
#define PARAMETER   20000  // over 24 bits, should throw a error at design time
...
#if PARAMETER > (1<<24)
#error PARAMETER > 24 bits
#endif
```

What you do here is not compile time checking but run time checking:

```
if(MyMacro(variable,PARAMETER))
{
    // do something
    //  do something WRONG because PARAMETER > 24 bits
}
```

but what is `variable` doing here anyway if you just want to know if `PARAMETER` is > 24 bits?

Comment: indeed, but I have a LOT of timers in application. will require to add this check for each one, isn't it? I am trying to check in (with) my macro itself

Comment: @orfruit no, you check it once in some header file. And please explain what `variable` is doing here??

Comment: @orfruit or just tell us what exactly `MyMacro(variable,PARAMETER)` is supposed to do. Make that clear in your question, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61813086/edit)

Comment: Please see edited with _Static_assert(), the macro is just a comparision test that's all