# Is it possible to use __asm as lambda expression in C99 (gcc/clang)

Tags: c, lambda

Is there a way to incorporate a `__asm` instruction into a C expression?

The idea is to somehow  substitute `b = expression` with `__asm(" ":"r" (b))` in

`a = b = expression`.

Unfortunately `__asm` is not recognized as expression. Is there a way to mimic `__asm` as a right-hand expression?

Comment: By wrapping it into a function or macro `do {} while` block? :-)

Comment: I think the inline-assembler notation in C is heavily compiler dependent. What compiler are you using ?

Comment: @JakobSachs, correct, I mean GCC/Clang(LLVM)

Comment: @oakad, unfortunately ```do while``` is not a right-hand expression - ```a = do {} while(0); ``` is not valid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does \_\_asm{}; return the value of eax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802683/does-asm-return-the-value-of-eax)

Comment: @JakobSachs , unfortunately No. ```a = __asm``` is not a valid statement

Comment: @JakobSachs Actually, looking more closely at what I had in mind, the real magic happens because of https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35148076/2702398)

Comment: Thats because `__asm` doesnt exist in GCC like it does int VC.
The first answer on that  post details a way how to emulate the same behaviour in GCC.

Comment: Do you need to pass this instruction to other functions? If so, you probably have to create a function for each one and place the asm instruction there and then pass a function pointer to that function.

Comment: The other solution would be to create the complete function for each possible asm instruction and call the correct function. Maybe make a function pointer table if you need to store which function you have to use.

Comment: I think what you really want is not possible on some architectures and other disable this by default for good reason. You shouldn't change the running code during execution of that code. Disabling this is also a security feature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX . If you really need it, you have to use assembler.