# Why is C source code sometimes wrapped with a do...while(0) loop?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there sometimes meaningless do/while and if/else statements in C/C++ macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-mac)

Why is C source code I run across sometimes wrapped with a `do...while(0)` loop?

```
do {
  parser->http_errno = e;                         
  parser->error_lineno = __LINE__;    
} while (0)
```

Why use that, versus this:

```
parser->http_errno = e;                         
parser->error_lineno = __LINE__;
```

I suspect this has something to do with thread safety, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your suspicion is absolutely, totally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done so that you can use it inside a macro, while requiring the macro user to use a semicolon at the end, just like a regular statement.

In other words, whenever you want *multiple* statements inside a function-like macro `FOO(...)`, you wrap it with `do { ... } while (0)` so that the user of the macro can (and, in fact, *must*) call it as `FOO(x);`, instead of simply `FOO(x)` (whose lack of semicolon can be weird for both humans and computers).

Comment: It's not just to disallow `FOO(x)`, but to prevent `if (foo) FOO(x); else BAR(x);` from breaking. The `{}` block would be the body of the `if`, and the `;` would be an extra empty statement separating the `if` from the `else`, making the `else` invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You see such code mostly in Macros and they behave as if they were function
  #define Whatever do ..... while(0)

and you use it like
Whatever();

Ups I see this question  was answered here before
[do { ... } while (0) — what is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

Corrected the link, thanks Rune.

Comment: That link is an infinite loop.