# Strange macro declaration in C

Tags: c, libusb, libusb-1.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there sometimes meaningless do/while and if/else statements in C/C++ macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-mac)
>   [do { … } while (0) what is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

Exploring libusb-1.0.9 source code, I have found such line (`./os/poll_windows.c:78`):

```
#define CHECK_INIT_POLLING do {if(!is_polling_set) init_polling();} while(0)
```

As for me this is the same like:

```
#define CHECK_INIT_POLLING if(!is_polling_set) init_polling();
```

Is there any reason to loop that expression?

**UPDATE:**

I couldn't still realize what'd be wrong after the answers, and the following example helped:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST if(test) foo();
#define TEST_DO do { if(test) foo(); } while(0)

int test = 1;
void foo() {
    printf("%s", "Foo called");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc > 1) TEST_DO; /* LINE 12 */
    else printf("%s", "skipping...");

    return 0;
}
```

If you put `TEST` at line 12, a compiler will give an error `"error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’"`.
 Hope, this will help someone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's to avoid errors that appear after the macro is substituted, for example, think about what happens if there's an `else` after your second version.