# Defining a Preprocessor Macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm relatively new to C++ and I'm taking a class on it. Our class was assigned a lab and my teacher has said that the lab write-up is a bit hard to understand; however, he did not make any changes to the lab write-up. So, I came across this part of the lab:

> **Defining a Preprocessor Macro**
>
> Long-standing convention capitalizes macro names, and this macro name must be TRACE_FUNC. The macro has a single parameter, a symbol that will be replaced by a function name when you apply the macro to the code. The start of the macro looks like this:
>
> ```
> #define TRACE_FUNC( symbol )  replacement-text`
> ```
>
> and the preprocessor will substitute the replacement text everywhere that the TRACE_FUNC( sym ) string exists in the source code, AND feed the symbol into that replacement.
>
> NOTE: the #define statement must be all on a single, logical line. To keep the length manageable, you can escape the newline character with a backslash at the end of the line; that will keep the preprocessor happy while allowing you to span a definition across multiple lines.
>
> For this exercise, the replacement text must be a complete statement, including the terminating semi-colon.
>
> The replacement text must be an output statement that prints the symbol followed by the text () called. and a newline to standard output. You can copy and modify one of the output statements from the warning.cpp source file.

`warning.cpp` is just a file we're using and `TRACE_FUNC` is being placed in a header file.

So, I read this a couple times and I'm not 100% sure what it's asking. Looking at it one way, it seems like it's asking me to create a macro called TRACE_FUNC. If you look at it another way, it's asking me to use the macro TRACE_FUNC. All of that is fine, but I don't know how to use TRACE_FUNC at all, I can't find any documentation on it anywhere and I don't know how to create a macro. When I asked for help, my teacher just kind of said. words and not ones that were very helpful because it was a very winding, confusing answer with no explanation of what TRACE_FUNC actually is.

Basically, all that my teacher said was that the symbol within `TRACE_FUNC` needs to be the name of one of the functions in the source code. As an example, say we had a function `foo()` within warning, then the symbol is supposed to be `foo()` (or foo, I'm not sure of that, either), from his explanation. Also, in the replacement text, apparently the name itself will be replaced if I put `#` in front of the symbol. I thought that supposed to denote preprocessor directives. Why am I supposed to be using it here?

Anyway, doing what my teacher says pretty much does nothing. Neither this line

`#define TRACE_FUNC( foo() ) #foo() called. ;`

nor this line

`#define TRACE_FUNC( foo ) #foo () called. ;`

replace any text, which I'm pretty sure is the operation of the #define directive. So I must be applying what my teacher said in the wrong way, but I don't really know why it's wrong or how to fix it.

**So, my question. Is `TRACE_FUNC` actually a macro and if so, is there any documentation on it that I can read? Or am I supposed to be creating `TRACE_FUNC` and if so, how exactly am I supposed to do that?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, what utter rubbish! You're supposed to be learning C++ right, not intricacies of the preprocessor.

Here's what you are supposed to be doing, though why is anyone's guess.

```
#define TRACE_FUNC(sym) std::cout << #sym << "() called\n"

void foo()
{
  TRACE_FUNC(foo);
  ...
}
```

I'm assuming that there are examples from warning.cpp that use `std::cout` if not then you'll have to adapt the above to whatever you find in warning.cpp.

The idea is that each function starts with a use of the TRACE_FUNC macro, so you can trace the execution of your code. Why the professor thinks this is a good idea for newbies is beyond me. Even if it were a good idea, that you are expected to figure out the details for yourself is even stupider.

I could improve the macro above but that would probably confuse even more so I won't. For now I would just do what the professor says but ignore it. Hopefully he'll get onto stuff that's worth learning later.

Comment: Thanks! This was much clearer than what my teacher was saying.

Comment: Also consider http://stackoverflow.com/a/257425/1689451 on how to define function macros.

Answer (score -1):

here is a example: use the ouput print function in your libray to replace the standard function printf here

```
 #define TRACE_FUNC(sym) printf("%s() called", #sym);
```

to use it as

```
TRACE_FUNC(printf)
```

the output should be

```
printf() called
```

your actual task is to print out a symbol in a defined format. so you need printf or similar function in your #define.