# NSAssert impementation

Tags: objective-c, macros

I opened snippet of the `NSAssert` and found this:

```
do {                \
    __PRAGMA_PUSH_NO_EXTRA_ARG_WARNINGS \
    if (!(condition)) {     \
         [[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInMethod:_cmd \
         object:self file:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] \
         lineNumber:__LINE__ description:(desc), ##__VA_ARGS__]; \
      }             \
    __PRAGMA_POP_NO_EXTRA_ARG_WARNINGS \
} while(0)
```

Why **do ... while(0)** was used? It will be allways performed one time.

Comment: Good question. I saw a similar macro snippet where pragma params were pushed and it was also wrapped in `do { ... } while(0)`. Would like to read the answer to this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for

Comment: It's a macro trick -- one of several ways to assure that if the macro will not accidentally interact with the program structure around it.  Eg, if one coded `if (someTest) NSAssert(...) else doSomething;` the logic of that would be mucked up without the surrounding do/while.