# how to use c macro with three lines of statement in c

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I would like to understand how to efficiently use C macros in my code.Can someone guide me with respect to the below mentioned code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void write_strongswan_conf(char buffer[1000],int buffer_size)
{
   FILE *fp;
   char delimiter[]="\n";
   fp = fopen( "strongswan.txt" , "a" );
   strcat(buffer,"\n");
   fwrite(buffer, 1 ,buffer_size+1, fp );
   printf("Data Written:%s",buffer);
   fclose(fp);
}

int main ()
{
    char wr_buffer[1000];
    int  wr_buffer_size =1;

    strcpy(wr_buffer,"STRONG SWAN CONFIGURATION FILE");
    wr_buffer_size = strlen(wr_buffer);
    write_strongswan_conf(wr_buffer,wr_buffer_size);

    strcpy(wr_buffer,"THIS IS THE SECOND LINE");
    wr_buffer_size = strlen(wr_buffer);
    write_strongswan_conf(wr_buffer,wr_buffer_size);

   return(0);
}
```

This is a small program to append new strings to the end of a file and i have around 25 strings to be added to the file.As of now, I have to repeatedly write the below mentioned three lines to get it done.If my understanding is correct we will be able to reduce the LOC by implementing a macro for these three lines.

Can someone guide me ?

```
    strcpy(wr_buffer,"STRONG SWAN CONFIGURATION FILE");
    wr_buffer_size = strlen(wr_buffer);
    write_strongswan_conf(wr_buffer,wr_buffer_size);
```

Comment: or even simpler by putting it in a function with the right parameters.

Comment: You want to write a multi-line macro? Simply end each line of the macro with "\"

Comment: thanks for your response.function is one way of doing it but i would like to understand the concept of macro and make use of the same.I know it will reduce the readability but i'm interested to learn about macro.

Comment: But among the three lines,The string will be different.In this case "STRONG SWAN CONFIGURATION FILE"

Comment: You will have to pass that as a string argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward:

```
#define FOO(buf, str) \
    strcpy(buf, str); \
    write_strongswan_conf(buf, strlen(buf));
```

Note that the buffer size argument was superfluous, so it is not needed here.

Then refer to it via:

```
int main ()
{
    char wr_buffer[1000];

    FOO(wr_buffer, "STRONG SWAN CONFIGURATION FILE");
    FOO(wr_buffer, "THIS IS THE SECOND LINE");

    return(0);
}
```

If you really did need a local argument in your macro, you could define a block with a macro:

```
#define FOO(buf, str) \
    { \
        int bsize; \
        strcpy(buf, str); \
        bsize = strlen(buf); \
        write_strongswan_conf(buf, bsize); \
    }
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to comments from @jweyrich and @BillLynch, they point out the [potential pitfalls with the above method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257425/298054), and it is preferred to render a code block as follows when in a macro:

```
#define FOO(buf, str) \
    do { \
        strcpy(out, str); \
        write_strongswan_conf(buf, strlen(str)); \
    } while (0)
```

The block structure has one other benefit, and that is if you want to use your macro in an a compound statement in C. If you take the first definition above and do this:

```
if ( some_check )
     FOO(wr_buffer, "STRONG SWAN CONFIGURATION FILE");
```

You wouldn't get the expected results since the `if` would only apply to the first of the three statements. Of course, one good solution is to always block your statements:

```
if ( some_check ) {
     FOO(wr_buffer, "STRONG SWAN CONFIGURATION FILE");
}
```

But you could also use the pattern `do { ... } while (0)` in the macro definition as shown in the second example above, and that would avoid the issue as well.

Note that it is sometimes important to parenthesize arguments in macro definitions. I did not do so above since it isn't likely an issue, but let's suppose you have a macro such as this:

```
#define MUL(X, Y)   (X * Y)
```

This looks innocent enough. Let's try it:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3
int c;

c = MUL(a, b);
```

This generates:

```
c = (a * b);
```

Note that `#define`s are quite literal. The parentheses are included. The preprocessor is just doing a direct substitution of everything I defined. If my expression is more complex:

```
c = MUL(a + 2, b + 3);
```

Then I get:

```
c = (a + 2 * b + 3);
```

Wait... this is going to give me a result which is equivalent to `a + (2*b) + 3` which is probably not what I wanted. So I define the macro more carefully with parentheses:

```
#define MUL(X, Y)  ((X) * (Y))
```

Now the above will expand to: `c = ((a + 2) * (b + 3));`.

By the way, if you get any strange behavior when using macros and/or other `#define`s, it can be handy to run just the preprocessor on your `.c` file which will expand all of the `#define`s without compilation. The output can be a bit unwieldy at first, but it's handy for identifying problems with macros that are complex. You can see exactly what it generated.

In Unix/Linux, you would just run the `cpp` command: `cpp myfile.c > myfile.pre` or whatever you want to call the file. If you're using Visual Studio, there's likely an option for generating the preprocessed file.

For the record, if it were me, I'd probably make this a function, not a macro. It certainly saves only a tiny percentage of execution timemaking something like this a macro.

As in all aspects of coding: it's important to think through and carefully about what you're doing. :)

Comment: That did the Job! Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need the `bsize` argument if the macro never reads its value. It's currently misleading.

Comment: @jweyrich I'm not sure I understand your comment. The `bsize` argument is used in `write_strongswan_conf(buf, bsize)`.

Comment: @lurker: Yes, but you simply overwrite it in your macro when you do `bsize = strlen(buf);`, so why pass it by argument in the 1st place? You completely ignores the value passed by the user.

Comment: @jweyrich technically it's not "overwriting" anything since it's a macro, not a function. The argument isn't "passed in" but substituted. If you expand the macro, you'll see that. However, the variable could be eliminated as I show in my update, and could have been in the original code in the same way as well.

Comment: Instead of a simple block, you really should suggest `do { statements; } while (false)`. And `({ statments; })` is a gcc extension.

Comment: @BillLynch thanks much for that suggestion. I hadn't seen that technique before for defining multi-statement macros. Looks like jweyrich beat me to it...

Comment: @lurker: This code will cause a syntax error: https://gist.github.com/sharth/106e7c80654094ebc127

Comment: @lurker: I meant you _overwrite_ its value. I missed a word, sorry.

Comment: @jweyrich (and @BillLync) gents: well this just proves to me there's always something more I can learn about macros! :)

Comment: If you enjoy macros, you may get some great insights from [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/)  (which you probably already know) written by [@Jens Gustedt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) - He wrote some great articles on [his blog](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/) too. Learned a lot from him!

Comment: @jweyrich lol well I don't know if I *enjoy* them, but I do like educating myself on topics I might dare to blurt something out about. So thanks for the handy links.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my shot:

```
#define DO_SOMETHING(buf, str) \
    do { \
        const char *in = str; \
        char *out = buf; \
        const size_t len = strlen(in); \
        strcpy(out, in); \
        write_strongswan_conf(out, len);
    } while (0)
```

What are the reasons behind writing the macro exactly this way?

1. The `do {} while(0)` is not strictly necessary, but that's the only way to have a multi-statement operation properly expanded inside a condition. For example, `if (condition) DO_SOMETHING(...)`. See a [more elaborate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257425/298054) about this.
2. The reason for creating temporary variables is that macro arguments are evaluated every time they appear in the macro body. For example, calling the macro `PRINT_ME_TWICE(intval) printf("%d\n", intval); printf("%d\n", intval);` with `PRINT_ME_TWICE(i++)` will print different values beucase the `intval` argument is evaluated twice, thus executing the post-increment operator (`++`) twice. You can only guarantee the evaluation problem won't happen by creating temporary variables, assigning the arguments to them, and never mention the arguments again.

**NOTE**: I'd argue against the use of `strcpy` if you can't guarantee the output buffer has enough space to hold the resulting string (plus the NULL terminator).

**UPDATE**:

As mentioned by [@Bill Lynch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47453/bill-lynch) in comments, the version above may still put you in trouble if you have variables with the same names the macro uses internally. This is known as [Variable Shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). Any good compiler should be able to issue a warning about that. GCC for instance warns you even compiling without `-Wall` or `-Wextra`. Currently, the best we can do for a macro is a mere attempt to minimize the risk of shadowing by prefixing the variable names in our macros. That may be a good practice, but it's not a real solution. This is how it would look like then:

```
#define DO_SOMETHING(buf, str) \
    do { \
        const char *DO_SOMETHING_in = str; \
        char *DO_SOMETHING_out = buf; \
        const size_t DO_SOMETHING_len = strlen(DO_SOMETHING_in); \
        strcpy(DO_SOMETHING_out, DO_SOMETHING_in); \
        write_strongswan_conf(DO_SOMETHING_out, DO_SOMETHING_len);
    } while (0)
```

A good advice would be to replace macros by proper functions whenever possible, avoiding all *obscurities* of macros.

Comment: Thanks for offering this. I was just about to update my post with this technique, but you beat me to it! (+1)

Comment: @lurker: Thanks! :-) No worries, if you update your answer I'll gladly upvote it as well! Maybe I should've edited yours in the 1st place. No disputes.

Comment: Your code will still have problems with this: https://gist.github.com/sharth/0eb6ebe7858de9ba49aa

Comment: @BillLynch: The variable shadowing? And, did you pass the arguments order backwards on purpose? (or their name are misleading)

Comment: @jweyrich: Right. The variable shadowing. And yeah, I passed particular variable names to cause an issue. That being said, `DO_SOMETHING(out, in);` will also fail spectacularly.

Comment: @BillLynch: I believe the best one can do to (attempt to) prevent shadowing in macros is to prefix variable names. Yet, a good compiler should be able to alert your about possible shadowing. Anyway, I'll update my answer to reflect this. Good point :-)

Comment: @jweyrich: Personally, the real solution is to use a function. And if necessary, simply write a macro to wrap the call to that function.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there is no call for a macro for this code.  Use an array instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void write_strongswan_conf(const char *buffer)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("strongswan.txt", "a");
    if (fp != 0)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", buffer);
        printf("Data Written: %s\n", buffer);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    static const char *conf_string[] =
    {
        "STRONG SWAN CONFIGURATION FILE",
        "THIS IS THE SECOND LINE",
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(conf_string) / sizeof(conf_string[0]); i++)
        write_strongswan_conf(conf_string[i]);

    return(0);
}
```

I'm blithely assuming it is sensible to open and close the file each time a string is written.  I'm not convinced that's the case, but the original code made the assumption.  (Opening a file is fairly expensive; you don't do it gratuitously, and that feels a bit gratuitous to me.)

The code in the `write_strongswan_conf()` function uses `fprintf()` instead of `fwrite()` since you're just writing strings, and that allows you to avoid concatenating a newline to the buffer, and therefore reduces the number of copies made.  In fact, you don't even need to know how long the strings are; `fprintf()` will do the counting for you.

There really isn't anywhere in the resulting code that benefits from being converted to a macro; there isn't any sufficiently large chunk of repetition.  The initialized array of strings can take 25 lines as well as it does 2.  The writing function can be used with other sources of data if you wish.  You could read the lines from another file, or have the user type them, or the program generate them.  It is not tied to 1000-character lines (give or take — 998 would be the maximum safe length of string in the original code) and could handle longer lines.  It error checks the `fopen()` call and doesn't try writing with a null file pointer if the `fopen()` fails; that avoids a crash.

Comment: Yeah,I think the method is much more better but l really wanted to understand the concept of c macros.All of the above comments and answers have really helped me for that.Thanks a lot guys..