# Can anyone explain this lex preprocessor output?

Tags: c, lex

I want to manipulate the output of lex. There is only one write to yyout, in the ECHO macro. The macro is surrounded by "#ifndef ECHO", so I am replacing it with my desired action. 
However, I want to be sure to correctly replicate the original lex behavior. Lex defines ECHO to this code fragment:

```
do { 
    if (fwrite( yytext, yyleng, 1, yyout )) {
        } 
    } while (0)
```

Can anyone guess why the output is not simply "fwrite(...)"?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

Answer (score 1):

```
do { .. } while (0)
```

is a convenient way to #define a multi-statement operation as pointed out by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for).

By

```
if (fwrite( yytext, yyleng, 1, yyout ))
```

I believe you're given an option to deal with `fwrite` failure.

Here you call `fwrite`  with **just** 1 element of size yyleng. Considering that `fwrite` returns the total number of elements written, the possible return values are just 0 and 1 - 0 indicating any failure and 1 indicating success.

Ideally(or actually it is?), it should have been

```
if (!fwrite( yytext, yyleng, 1, yyout ))
```

I'm guessing this because, only block is given to write the fallback/logging code.

Comment: That explains the do loop - thx for the link. But it doesn't explain the empty if statement. The code fragment is the code in its entirety - no elisions.

Comment: @RobertREvans : By the way, did you compile lex from source? It's worth checking its documentation for this. :)