# Is this a loop?

Tags: c, loops, semantics

Is this a loop, not a loop, or both a loop and not a loop?  If you're counting the number of loops in a program, would you count this?

```
do {
   ...
}while(0);
```

I'm curious because I'm working with someone who has a project that requires him to count the number of loops in a program.

Comment: It's a while loop, despite the false value, so I assume it is.

Comment: It's as much a loop as `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @Richie obvoiusly a good link, but not a dupe here.

Comment: @KerrekSB please tell me more about the *errr...*

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs: Seriously? What ever happened to just [trying it out yourself](http://ideone.com/RhGHca) before posting?

Comment: The compiler might completly optimize away the `while` construct, so all that would be left in the compiled binary is the `...` part.

Comment: BTW why would you need to know the number of loops in your program ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz - `re: "why would you need to know...."`, homework, for sure

Comment: You are effectively asking for a definition of "loop".  To the extent that there is any uncertainty or room for disagreement, this is a matter of opinion, and thus not appropriate for an SO question.

Comment: I don't see the point in counting the number of loops, a better approach IMHO would be counting the time complexities of the loops. This one in particular has O(1).

Comment: This question does not ask about the usage of `do...while..`, as was in the marked dupes. As I already commented, IMHO, this is not a dupe, please let me know if anyone disagrees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C standard, `C11`, chapter §6.8.5, *Iteration statements*, it is listed

> *iteration-statement:*
>
> `while  (` *expression* `) statement`
>        `do` *statement* `while (` *expression* `) ;`
>        `for (` *expression* <sub>opt</sub> ; *expression* <sub>opt</sub> ; *expression* <sub>opt</sub> `) statement`
>        `for (` *declaration expression* <sub>opt</sub> ; *expression* <sub>opt</sub> `) statement`

The `do statement while ( expression ) ;` is mentioned, so **yes, it is a loop (iteration) statement**, *irrespective* of the number of iterations it make in a particular implementation/usage.

FWIW, this loops one time.

To add some more clarification, [quoting from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Loops), (*emphasis mine*)

> A loop is a sequence of statements which is *specified once* but which **may be** *carried out several times* in succession. The code "inside" the loop (the body of the loop, shown below as xxx) is obeyed a specified number of times, or once for each of a collection of items, **or until some condition is met**, or indefinitely.

Comment: Are all loop statements necessarily also loops then?

Comment: @vjb words can be tricky. this is obviously a _loop statement_ with an iteration of _exactly_ one time.

Answer (score 2):

In a sense, yes it is a loop, but in reality no. It is technically a loop because you are using loop syntax, but what you're actually doing is just running the code in your "loop" once, and then breaking. I wouldn't really count it as a loop because you're not adding any algorithmic runtime to your program, so there's no point in counting it as a loop. Note: don't do this, it is pointless and bad coding practice.

EDIT: Credits to Jeremy in the comments below, there is at least one case where this construct can be useful in C: [do { ... } while (0) — what is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

Comment: It's also an enormously widespread construct used in almost every macro.

Comment: @KerrekSB At least, one would hope so. In reality, many macros are made without this…

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for

Comment: unless of course some condition internally 'runs' a `continue' and then you run more than once

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Can you make an example and link to it?

Comment: @KerrekSB - can't figure out where to store an example but `do { ....; i = getVar(); if (i < 0) continue; .....; } while (0);`

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I don't understand at which part of your code you "run more than once".

Comment: @KerrekSB - you are correct, I forgot that `continue` does not go to the top of the loop but instead goes to the control statement - Mea Culpa and thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
   ...
}while(k);
```

Now the number of iterations depend on the value of `k`, now you cant say something like its a loop only if `k!=0` or if `k` is `True`.

So its basically a loop.