# Print filename saved at compile time

Tags: c, string, macros, filenames

My goal is to print the filenames and not relative path to the filename. I'm experimenting with it using the macro `TRACE()`.
Since it's all in the same file, I'm simulating the filename as an input to `TRACE()`. So in real life, you could say the inputs are replaced with `__FILE__`.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)

#define __FILENAME__(x) TOSTRING(strrchr(x, '\\'))

#define TRACE(s, ...) \
    { \
    if (strrchr(s, '\\')) { \
        static const char str[] = __FILENAME__(s) "\n\r"; \
        printf(str, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    } else { \
        static const char str[] = s "\n\r"; \
        printf(str, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    } \
    }

int main() {
    TRACE("file.c");
    TRACE("parent\\file.c");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
file.c
strrchr("parent\\file.c", '\\')
```

So if it's local file, it's printed as `file.c`, which is great. This means the `if`case in the macro is working :). But when it's a file in another folder, I fail to "stringify" the computation `strrchr(s, '\\')`. Why?

Furthermore, I don't see an issue with the computation in the define, since everything is defined at compile time!! (That's why the `if` case is working, right?)

If I remove the `TOSTRING()` from `__FILENAME__` I get loads of errors instead. Because it fails to concatenate the output of `__FILENAME__` with `str[]`

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but all symbols starting with two leading underscores (or one leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter) are reserved in all scopes for "the implementation" (compiler and standard library). You should not use such symbols yourself anywhere.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Check!

Comment: *I don't see an issue with the computation in the define, since everything is defined at compile time* -- No, the correct branch is chosen at runtime.

Comment: `TOSTRING(strrchr(s, '\\'))` is converted as `"strchr(s, '\\')" `. Is this what you want?

Comment: not related - placing brackets one over another reduces the readability and it's considered a bad practice.Instead of placing the macro in a "block" with brackets i would recommend using "do-while".

Comment: Note that it is more conventional to use `\r\n` than `\n\r` at the end of a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Preliminary observations

Note that in C (as opposed to C++), you can't initialize a `static const char str[]` array with the result of a function call.  If the `strrchr()` found a backslash, you probably want to print the name from one after the backslash.  And the stringification isn't going to stringify the result of invoking `strrchr()`.

Also note that you should not create function or variable names that start with an underscore, in general. [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says (in part):

> - *All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.*
> - *All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.*

See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449301/15168)

Since the first argument to your TRACE macro is already a string, there's not much benefit to applying the stringification — unless you want the double quotes to appear when the name is printed.

#### Simple adaptation

To get more or less the result you want, you would need to accept that there'll be run-time overhead invoking `strrchr()` each time you pass the trace (or a more elaborate scheme for initialization), along the lines of:

```
#define TRACE(s, ...) \
    do { \
        const char *basename = strrchr(s, '\\'); \
        if (basename == 0) \
            basename = s; \
        else \
            basename++; \
        printf(basename, ## __VA_ARGS__); \
    } while (0)
```

The `do { … } while (0)` idiom is standard; it allows you to write:

```
if (something)
    TRACE("hocuspocus.c: test passed\n");
else
    TRACE("abracadabra.c: test failed\n");
```

If you use the braces-only notation in the question, the semicolon after the first TRACE makes the `else` into a syntax error.  See also [C `#define` macro for debug printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing/1644898#1644898) and [Why use apparently meaningles `do { … } while (0)` and `if … else` statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros) and [`do { … } while (0)` — what is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

The `## __VA_ARGS__` trick is fine as long as you know that it is a GCC (and Clang because it is compatible with GCC) extension, and not a part of standard C.

It also isn't entirely clear how you plan to use the variable arguments.  It looks as though you'd be able to do:

```
TRACE("some\\kibbitzer.c: value %d is out of the range [%d..%d]\n",
      value, MIN_RANGE, MAX_RANGE);
```

where the file name is embedded in the format string.  Maybe you have in mind:

```
TRACE(__FILE__ ": value %d is out of the range [%d..%d]\n",
      value, MIN_RANGE, MAX_RANGE);
```

That can work; `__FILE__` is a string literal, unlike `__func__` which is a predefined identifier (`static const char __func__[] = "…function name…";`).

Finally (for now), consider whether trace output should go to standard output or to standard error.  It is easily arguable it should go to standard error; it (probably) isn't part of the regular output of the program.

I recommend looking at the 'debug macro' question and answer — but I am biassed since I wrote the top-scoring answer.

#### Reducing runtime overhead

You can reduce the runtime overhead to a single call to `strrchr()` per file name, as long as you aren't messing with automatic variables etc.  You'll be OK if you're using string literals.

```
#define TRACE(s, ...) \
    do { \
        static const char *basename = 0;
        if (basename == 0) \
        {
            if ((basename = strrchr(s, '\\')) == 0) \
                basename = s; \
            else \
                basename++; \
        } \
        printf(basename, ## __VA_ARGS__); \
    } while (0)
```

This initializes the `basename` to null; on the first pass through the code, `basename` is set to the correct position in the string; thereafter, there is no further call to `strrchr()`.

<sup>***Warning:** the code shown has not been compiled.*</sup>

Comment: Excellent answer! Great links. Works! But it's like you say regarding the "run-time overhead". Anyway, accepting since this answers the question, as opposed to "you shouldn't do that"-answers.

Comment: See the addendum for how you can reduce the runtime overhead.

Comment: I will, tnx. But preferably I would like to skip runtime overall and have it in compile time like I do when using `__FILE__`. But then you get the entire relative path. It amazes me that `__FILENAME__` isn't built in gcc

Comment: It appears `%` is not [reserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) as a file name character.  Certain to create havoc with OP's `TRACE()`.

Comment: Not enough people have felt a need for it., where 'enough people' might only need to be one person if they're willing to make and document the change.  However, since you're using GCC, you should read the [manual]( https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros) on common macros.  There's a `__BASE_FILE__` macro. _[…time passes…]_  Oh; that's the `__FILE__` for the main source file being compiled, even if you're processing a header or other file at the time.  No help.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some issue with the understanding of how macros and functions work.

Macros are not "executed", they are just simple text substitution. Yes, that happens in the compile time (actually pre compiling), but just the substitution.

Macros won't execute and code or call any functions (like `strrchr`) while compiling.

In your code you have -

```
#define __FILENAME__(x) TOSTRING(strrchr(x, '\\'))
```

Whenever `__FILENAME__(foo)` is used, it is replaced with `"strrchr(foo, '\\')"`. I am sure this is not what you want.

Personally, I don't see any reason for using macros here. Just make it into a normal function. The compiler will optimize it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But I can't accept this as an answer.

Comment: You might note that the parameter to the macro you quoted is `x`, but the expansion references `s`.  That glitch has been fixed in the question since you wrote your answer — you might care to update it to that (because, as written, `__FILENAME__(foo)` is translated to `strrchr(s, '\\')` regardless of what is provided as an argument.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, I will fix that. I had copied the line from the question. Don't know how it slipped my eye.