# C language syntax: if { ... } while(0);

Tags: c

I am looking at https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/s20161105/ping.c and I see from lines 608-713:

```
if (source.sin_addr.s_addr == 0) {
... // Omitted
} while(0);
```

Two questions:

1. How it compiles
2. What is the value of adding `while (0)` after if statement

Comment: The code is VERY poorly written and organized.  Starting with the header file: `ping.h`  contains a mix of `#includes`, struct definitions, and `inline static` functions.  Also the github code will NEVER compile.  There are MANY problems including the call to `print_timestamp();`in the code, but the prototype is: `extern void print_timestamp(struct ping_rts *rts);`  Note: this prototype occurs 4 times in the code. Suggest either planning on doing a LOT of work to correct the code -or- find another project

Comment: There are two theories I have about the code you referenced. First, it looks a lot like this code was ripped out of a complex macro; often they're implemented with `do{...}while(0)` to allow them to be used like functions and not immediately cause a line-termination. The other theory is that it is an *obfuscation canary*: these are weak (usually do-nothing) idioms occasionally littered around that can help determine if someone stole an open-source implementation (that is, violated the OSS license of the code).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's two statements in succession. Entirely equivalent to this

```
if(/* ... */) {
  // Body
}
while(0) {
  // empty
}
```

`while(0);` is just a loop with a single empty statement for a body.

There is no value in adding it after the `if`. I suspect it's leftover from a previous refactoring, but the git history in that repository does not go that far.

Answer (score 4):

1. It compiles because it is two statements, first

   ```
   if (...) { ... }
   ```

   followed by another statement

   ```
   while (0);
   ```

   i.e. a loop with empty body that is never run.
2. There is no value. `while (0);` as a separate statement is utterly useless. [`do { ... } while (0)` is not useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for) but it is a completely different thing.

---

Probably the code was refactored from a form that initially used `do { ... } while (0)` and using `break`s to exit the flow early (from the linked question above). Currently the source file does not have *any* instances of `do` statement, there are only 3 times that the verb *do* exists in some strings.