# How to print logs on both console and file in C language?

Tags: c, printf

I have come across many questions related to this but my requirement is quite different. I developed a C application(`mib-test.c`) earlier which uses `fprintf` at lot of places. `fprintf` logs the messages in a file.

But now I need to print these messages to console also. I am looking for a solution in which I do not need to change `fprintf` in all the places.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but you can either `tail -f` the file in another terminal; or use the `tee` function to create a file descriptor that can write to both stdout and a file.

Comment: @eduffy OP wants the out that goes to file to also go to the console, not the opposite.

Comment: Maybe it's technically possible, but certainly not in a good way.

Comment: @klutt well yeah, technically you could re-define your own `fprintf`... but that's just awful...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Ouch, that code smells :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not, you will have to edit each instance. A better approach to begin with would have been to create your own logging function or macro. I would suggest you to do that now, and save yourself some time if you ever change mind again in the future.

Example using a function:

```c
void log(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(logfile, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Example using a macro:

```c
#define log(fmt, ...) do {                                    \
                          fprintf(stderr, fmt, __VA_ARGS__);  \
                          fprintf(logfile, fmt, __VA_ARGS__); \
                      } while (0)
```

See also: [do { ... } while (0) — what is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

**Note that** using a macro will evaluate expressions twice. For example `log("%d\n", get_int());` using the macro form will call `get_int()` twice. You should only use the macro if you plan to pass simple values.

Both solutions assume that `logfile` is global and already opened for writing. You could actually define it `static` inside the function and handle the initial opening checking `if (logfile == NULL)` before doing anything.

Comment: This evaluates the macro arguments twice.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't get your macro to work: https://onlinegdb.com/Hyv9JkGPP

Comment: @klutt you need at least one argument after the format string (otherwise why use `fprintf` in the first place?). You'd need another macro if you want to also handle the case of zero additional args.

Comment: Then I definitely prefer the function. Requiring an extra argument seems a bit meh. Furthermore, you should name it something else than `log` since that function exists in math.h

Comment: @klutt of course if you don't need to output any arguments then just hard code the format string: `#define log(...) do { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __VA_ARGS__); ...`

Answer (score 1):

@marcobonelli wrote a great answer. So for the replacing part, if you're not using an IDE that can do all the replacements for you, you could probably use this simple `sed` command to do all the replacement. Assume you have a `log` function like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64318439/6699433), then just do this:

```
sed 's/fprintf(logfile/log(/g' -i <file>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is incomplete (error handling is omitted), but it demonstrates the principle of replacing filedescriptors via `dup()` and `dup2()`:

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int errtee(char * path);

        /*
        ** Function to write to *both* stderr and a named file
        ** Return the new filedescriptor, which should be
        ** used instead of STDERR_FILENO.
        ** (or -1 on error)
        */
int errtee(char * path){

    int out[2];
    pipe(out);
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid<0){ // error
        perror( "fork() failed\n" );
        return -1;
        }
    if(pid>0){ // parent
        close(out[0]);
        return out[1];
    }
    if(pid==0){ // child
        int fd_extra;
        char buff[512];

        fd_extra = open(path, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0666);
        if (fd_extra < 0) return -1;
        close(out[1]);
        dup2(out[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(out[0]);
        while(1) {
                unsigned done, todo;
                int cnt, this;
                cnt = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, sizeof buff) ;
                if (cnt <=0) break;
                for(todo = cnt, done = 0; done < todo; done += this) {
                        this = write(STDERR_FILENO, buff+done, todo-done);
                        if (cnt <=0) break;     // this is not perfect ...
                        }

                for(todo = cnt, done = 0; done < todo; done += this) {
                        this = write(fd_extra, buff+done, todo-done);
                        if (cnt <=0) break;     // this is not perfect ...
                        }
                }
        close( fd_extra);
    }
 exit(0);
}

int main(void){
    int new_fd;
    int old_fd;
    char buff[222];

    new_fd = errtee("Mylogfile.log" );
        if (new_fd < 0) {
        perror( "errtee() failed\n" );
        exit(1);
        }
        // Save the stdin filedescriptor
    old_fd = dup( STDERR_FILENO);
        // ... and replace it by the one from the subprocess.
    dup2(new_fd, STDERR_FILENO);

        // Send some output to stderr ...
    while (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin) ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", buff);
        }

        // Restore the old stdin filedescriptor
    dup2(old_fd, STDERR_FILENO);

        // ... and check if stderr still works  ...
    fprintf(stderr,"Completed\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

---

Note: diagnostic output should go to stderr. If you keep it that way, it can always be replaced by a method like above.

[It is also possible to fetch the fileno() from the fopen'd log file, and do it the other way around. YMMV]