# Test return value and return

Tags: c++, return, c++17

This may be a silly question, but I am working if there is a concise way to test the return result of a function, and, if it fails to meet a condition, return that value (i.e., pass it on).

To address a possible question right now, yes, what I am looking for is similar to what exceptions offer.  However, as an embedded developer, the overhead associated with exceptions (unfortunately) is too high a cost to pay.

For example,

```
enum class Status
{
    OKAY,
    ERROR1,
    ERROR2,
    ERROR3
};

Status foo1();
Status foo2();
Status foo3();

Status bar()
{
    Status result;

    result = foo1();
    if (result != Status::OKAY) return result;
   
    result = foo2();
    if (result != Status::OKAY) return result;

    result = foo3();
    if (result != Status::OKAY) return result;

    return Status::OKAY;
}
```

If I was just using a bool as the return value, a shorthand would be to write the following:

```
bool bar()
{
    if (!foo1()) return false;
    if (!foo2()) return false;
    if (!foo3()) return false;

    return true;
}
```

A side-effecting if clause like this is considered a code smell, but this seems more readable and concise to me than local variable assignments and tests.

Is there a a shorthand way to accomplish the same readability as the second example but with the same effect as the first example?

Comment: `operator bool()` perhaps?

Comment: If you do it this way you can collapse it to `return foo1() && foo2() && foo3()`

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. FWIW, I consider the code in your first block to be idiomatic. If you tried to roll your own abstraction around this it might make it harder to maintain. I understand the frustration. Last time I worked with cURL I had methods that looked like this.

Comment: `result = foo1(); if (result != Status::OKAY) return result;` can become `if (auto ret = foo1(); ret != Status::OKAY) return ret;`  That can easily be wrapped in a macro if you want to condense down the syntax.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's news to me. I didn't realize you could declare locals inside the clause of an if statement, same as a for loop.

Comment: It was added in C++17

Comment: Since your code only has boolean logic, it reduces to : `return foo1() && foo2() && foo3();`  If statements stop processing when they know that the answer can longer be true, so if `foo1() == false` then `foo2()` will not be called.

Comment: What about std::expected?  It’s going to be added in c++23 but you can use tl::expected now (which to my understanding became std::expected).  https://github.com/TartanLlama/expected

Comment: "the overhead associated with exceptions (unfortunately) is too high a cost to pay" - I've heard that sooo many times over the past 25+ years, but every time I've tried to get someone to substantiate the claim it has turned into fluff... I'm not buying that argument - especially not in 2023 (it might have had a bit of weight around 1999).

Comment: @JesperJuhl To be clear, I am NOT against exceptions and think they are the correct approach.  However, on an embedded system, using the arm-none-eabi-g++ compiler, I tried compiling with exceptions but the binary size increased too significantly.

Comment: @PatrickWright May I suggest trying a build with `-O2` (or `-O3`) combined with `-flto`? LTO tends to be *really* good at bringing down binary size (as well as increasing performance).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I will need to do some more fiddling to get link-time optimizations work.  The last time I tried to enable them, I saw no different at all in the final binary (which makes no sense).  I can only guess that the compiler version I am using is missing something...  But I do want to get a good side-by-side comparison of (messy) non-exception code vs. using exceptions.

Comment: @PatrickWright In my experience; Declaring leaf classes as `final` can also sometimes help bring down binary size by making it easier for the compiler to devirtualize function calls in some cases (especially combined with LTO) - might be something to also look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using C++17, you could write your `bar()` function like this, which isn't too bad, IMO:

```
Status bar() {
    if (auto result = foo1(); result != Status::OKAY) return result;
    if (auto result = foo2(); result != Status::OKAY) return result;
    if (auto result = foo3(); result != Status::OKAY) return result;
    return Status::OKAY;
}
```

Or, a lambda could come in handy as well. Although, I find it less appealing in this particular situation:

```
Status bar() {
    auto result = Status::OKAY;
    auto const check = [&result](auto foo) -> bool
    { return (result = foo()) != Status::OKAY; };

    if (check(foo1)) return result;
    if (check(foo2)) return result;
    if (check(foo3)) return result;
    return result;
}
```

Maybe writing your own functor works better:

```
Status bar() {
    struct {
        Status result;
        bool operator()(Status (&foo)())
        { return (result = foo()) != Status::OKAY; };
    } check{};

    if (check(foo1)) return check.result;
    if (check(foo2)) return check.result;
    if (check(foo3)) return check.result;
    return check.result;
}
```

Another way, is to take advantage of aggregate initialization, but this is stretching it a bit in terms of trickery.

```
Status bar() {
    struct convert {
        Status result;
        explicit operator bool() const
        { return result != Status::OKAY; }
    } check{};

    if ((check = convert{foo1()})) return check.result;
    if ((check = convert{foo2()})) return check.result;
    if ((check = convert{foo3()})) return check.result;
    return check.result;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/KnrWjav7z)

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I'd declare your `if` init-expressions `const`: `if(const auto result = ... ` since they are independent of each other and don't change. [Declare an object const...](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es25-declare-an-object-const-or-constexpr-unless-you-want-to-modify-its-value-later-on)

Comment: @Casey Thanks for your suggestion, and I agree it's a good rule of thumb in general. However, for a single line if-statement, which I think are only good in combination with a single return-statement (one way to prevent to write deeper scopes), I think it adds little value. I would even argue that in some scenarios, like this one but with function parameters too, it's actually best omitted.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is use a macro:

```
enum class Status
{
    OKAY,
    ERROR1,
    ERROR2,
    ERROR3
};

#define CHECK_STATUS(call_site)\
    do {\
      Status result = call_site;\
      if (result != Status::OKAY) return result;\
    } while(0)

Status foo1();
Status foo2();
Status foo3();

Status bar()
{
    CHECK_STATUS(foo1());
   
    CHECK_STATUS(foo2());
    
    CHECK_STATUS(foo3());

    return Status::OKAY;
}
```

If you're puzzled by the `do ... while(0)`, check this: [do { ... } while (0) — what is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

Comment: `CHECK_STATUS` -> `RETURN_IF_STATUS_IS_NOT_OKAY`.

Comment: I've actually written something like this before in my code.  I got shot down though because using a macro like this introduces a "dialect."

Comment: @PatrickWright It does, but are (simple) dialects a bad thing they are understood within a team? I'd say that if OP is coding by himself, this is probably fine. If they're part of a team, there should be a senior engineer that knows the commonly-accepted way to work in the team.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon @NathanOliver's comment on my question, I wrote the following possible solution.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Status
{
    OKAY,
    TOO_SMALL,
    TOO_LARGE
};

bool operator!(Status s)
{
    return s != Status::OKAY;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Status s)
{
    switch(s)
    {
    case Status::OKAY:
        os << "OKAY";
        break;
    case Status::TOO_SMALL:
        os << "TOO_SMALL";
        break;
    case Status::TOO_LARGE:
        os << "TOO_LARGE";
        break;
    }
    
    return os;
}

Status bar(int a)
{
    if (a < 5) return Status::TOO_SMALL;
    if (a > 10) return Status::TOO_LARGE;
    else return {};
}

Status foo(int a)
{
    if (auto r = bar(a); !r) return r;
    if (auto r = bar(a + 1); !r) return r;
    if (auto r = bar(a - 1); !r) return r;
        
    return {};
}

void test(int a)
{
    auto result = foo(a);
    std::cout << "foo(" << a << ") -> " << result << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test(8);
    test(5);
    test(10);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I simplified the conditional testing of the enum by overloading the ! operator.