# do { } while(0) alternative in macro definition or any other possible options

Tags: c, macros, definition, conventions

I have encountered a way of making a multiline macro function definition in C/C++ compilation, that does not meet any clear code conventions (and possibly creates performance drawbacks?). Is it the only way to achieve the goal of making macro functions? Are developers going to introduce any other ways to do it?

I see that is not the first question about while(0), but I'm looking for any possible alternatives, maybe I should just write normal functions.

I can see that that this technique is used in the Linux kernel, thus may I say that it's legal to write like that?
[Linux repository search](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Atorvalds%2Flinux+while%280%29&type=code&p=2)

Comment: Why do you want alternatives? What's the issue with `do ... while (0)`? It definitely doesn't have "performance drawbacks".

Comment: *"maybe I should just write normal functions"* Yes, you should write normal functions. Macros should be the last resort.

Comment: What do you mean "does not meet any clear code conventions"?  The practice of using `do {} while(0)` in a macro has been around for a long time and is very conventional.  It is an extremely common idiom.

Comment: Check out [What is do { } while(0) in macros and should we use it?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/279576) As mentioned there, it matters if you are writing a library used by unknowns, or just some end application. Macros in general is always the last resort though, if you can use a function instead, then use a function.

Comment: "I can see that that this technique is used in Linux kernel" The Linux kernel is literally as far from canonical C code as you can get.

Comment: @Lundin Yep. Linus said in an interview that because everything a user is running runs on top of the kernel, it's basically impossible to say that any performance issue in the kernel does not matter. Therefore, everything needs to be highly optimized.

Comment: A change would require a change in the pre-processor, the pre-processor is not C.  But to do that would be to cause incompatibility and encourage a generally ill-advised practice.  Function in-lining makes the practice largely unnecessary.  If this introduces a performance hit,  your compiler is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Macros and clear code don't mix well in the first place. That's basically just the way it is.

And yes, `do ... while(0)` is a bit of a clunky workaround. However, it has become a defacto standard of how to do what you want to do. If you find some other clever alternative, you will likely make the code less clear, because C programmers recognize the `do ... while(0)` as the established convention.

Don't worry about performance. Any compiler can see that `do ... while(0)` will be executed only once and will optimize the loop away.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257425/6699433) it's the only way to do what you want to do. I don't know if it's technically true, but I'm pretty sure there are no good ways around it. At least not for all situations. In some situations it can work to use the comma operator, like `#define FOO(x) a(x), b(x)` but that will not work for more complicated situations. However, there are also situations where you will have to use that approach. For instance, if you use `if(FOO(x))` the do-while will give an error, but the neither comma nor do-while does not work for `a = FOO(x)`. You can make it work with `#define FOO(x) (a(x), b(x))`, but you will still be limited to very simple constructs.

I try to stay away from macros whenever possible. They tend to make debugging much harder.

Answer (score 1):

At very first: Macros typically are harder to read and often make debugging more complicated – if applicable, functions or other alternatives, if the concrete use case allows, should be preferred.

If macros cannot be avoided for whatever reason, then actually it *would* work to simply wrap multiple expressions within a pair of braces. The `do { } while(0)` approach, though, enforces placing a semicolon afterwards, which is desirable to produce clean code (usage of the macro looks like a function call or other kind of single expression) and prevents usage of outside of functions (though the macros wrapped code usually would do so as well). So just wrapping into braces is clearly inferior to the `do { } while(0)` approach.

Actually there *appears* to be yet another alternative:

```
#define FOO if(1) { /* multiple expressions */ } else ((void)0)
```

[Chris Kline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434413/chris-kline) highlights in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154138/1312382) to a similar question the superiority of over the `do { } while(0)` approach in respect of safety in the case of the macro argument themselves containing (complex) code. However writing macros in such kind can be considered **dirty** code and should *not ever* be applied; in contrast this variant silently discards subsequent expressions e.g. if appended via the sequence (comma) operator like:

```
FOO, bar();
//   ^ unexpectedly won't get called!
```

so doesn't guarantee safe usage!

Comment: His comment is nonsense, anyone writing abominations like `MYMACRO(  SomeFunc(i)==true, {break;}  )` _deserve_ to get macro problems.

Comment: This is a bad alternative, because `FOO, bar();` (or `FOO + bar()`, etc) silently skips calling `bar()`, while `do{ }while(0)` would give you a compilation error instead.

Comment: I meant `static_assert(true)` (don't remember if I wrote `true` or `false` originally).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Hm... Indeed, this seems to do the trick. But the question is tagged C, so doesn't appear appropriate to me, suppose I won't add.

Comment: Consider more succinct version: `if(0);else{ ... }`. It will be resistant to tail-expression as well.

Comment: @tstanisl That's actually equivalent to simply wrapping braces around, just more complex, again the drawback is not enforcing the semicolon.

Comment: Indeed, maybe just leave an empty else `if(1){ ... }else`. I'm not sure that is to gain from `(void)0`.

Comment: @tstanisl Leaving an empty `else` is even worse, Assume `FOO` was defined that way and someone wrote e.g. `FOO /*note the forgotten semicolon*/ { std::lock_guard(myMutex) g; /* some protected action */ }` – I'd say self-explaining, isn't it? And yes, this is C++, just that it's a scenario natural to have braces surrounding some code (RAII!)…